# Search operator for featured question - How to search featured question?

Tags: feature-request, questions, search, featured-page

When we search a question on Stack Overflow we could use operators

https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

There are many nice search operators like `answers:0`, `lastactive:48h`,  `score:-1` etc. It would be nice to add an other operator for featured (bounty) questions. like `featured:yes` this would be useful for filtering featured questions page.

Comment: Unrelated, but the "Posts containing XX" list does not show attached bonuses... That said, if you are looking for Featured questions in your favourite tag list: click the tag and you'll see it has a tab of its own.

Answer (score 11):

Borrowing from [Shadow Wizards answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200242/158100) you could search for notices:

[hasnotice:1 locked:0 closed:no is:question lastactive:14d..](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasnotice%3A1+locked%3A0+closed%3Ano+is%3Aquestion+lastactive%3A14d..)

but that does show a couple of false positives...

It would be easier to click the [blue bounties number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size) and then apply filters there, that's if you're using the new nav. Otherwise you're stuck with the "[featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured)" tab.

Comment: "blue bounties number" doesn't seem to do anything now. I'm shown the "Interesting" tab (the default) instead.

Comment: @NirIzr the needs answers tab doesn't seem to exist anymore. I've updated the link but I'm on new nav so your millage may vary.

Comment: What's "new nav"? I get a "page not found" error

Comment: @NirIzr this one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate looks like I'm still opted in for beta testing

Comment: @NirIzr I found Sam to be kind enough to figure out how it is done *the old way* ...see his edit.

Comment: I'm aware of the festured tab. Already signed up for the new nav beta anyway. Thank you both!