# Bug in the new tabbed navigation when adding new tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

I am just exploring the [new tabbed navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) and I noticed when I try to add a new tag, and upon clicking the tag that I want from the suggestions, the tag description div comes on the top of the page instead below the tag which happens by default.

Here's a screenshot
[image]

I understand that this just rolled out, but I spotted this and I thought I'd let the guys know about the design bug.

EDIT: Browser: Firefox 38.0.5
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: I get this too but I assumed it was on purpose.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Browser: Firefox 38.0.5 OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: It's an intermittent bug in the tag editor, it also happens in the ask question page, randomly

Comment: Confirmed on CentOS 7, latest Firefox ESR (38.3.0)

Comment: No repro on Firefox 41, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I see this when adding _or_ removing a tag - Firefox 41.0.1  Chrome 46.0.2490.80  Safari 9.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a fun one. Our standard popup logic uses delegation `$(document).on({mouseenter: ..., mouseleave: ...})`. After the element is deleted, the `mouseleave` event doesn't reach `document`, and the showing of the popup was not canceled.

A fix for this is rolling out in the next build (build rev `2015.10.28.3791` on MSE/MSO, `2015.10.28.2910` on sites)..

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me too, but it occurred when I removed a tag, not when I added it. I can reproduce it 100% consistently. I am using Chrome, if that matters.

Steps to reproduce:

- Navigate to Stack Overflow
- Click on Questions
- Type in any tag and click to filter the list
- Click on the "x" to remove the tag filter
- Continue hovering where the tag filter used to be

Expected outcome:

- The filter would be removed and the page would look normal

Actual outcome:

- The filter was removed, but a tooltip stuck permanently at the top left corner of the page. Here is a photo.

[image]

If you hover or too long, the tooltip will appear where it should, and you will not be able to reproduce. In that case, refresh the page and try again.

Comment: Happens in Firefox too.

Comment: @JonH For testing, I have used IE 7,8 too sometimes

Comment: Also applies to Safari 9