# RSS and Subscribe Pop Up comes in left Top

Tags: bug, new-nav, tag-dropdown

When i seeing following pop up again and again if i follow the listed steps:

1. Click on any tag from "Explore our questions" Section. Tag will come in textbox to filter the question the basis of tags. where we can more tags as well.
2. Now just click on remove icon of tag you had selected. it will you the Subscriber and RSS pop up in left top corner.

[image: RSS And Subscribe Pop up]

According to me it should not be like the way it is going on. even we hover on the tag we entered in filter box. it opens subscribe box.

I might be wrong.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308877/bug-in-the-new-tabbed-navigation-when-adding-new-tag

Comment: @m0sa i didn't checked the previously asked question for same.. thanks for reviewing and marking duplicate.. :) . please let me know if you guys want me to delete this. so we can reduce duplicate things in our DB