# How to filter questions based on favorite tags with the new filter tabs

Tags: support, new-nav

How can I filter the questions based on my favorite tags with the new navigation on the questions overview? It seems to be impossible. With the old navigation I could choose 'Favorites' from the dropdownmenu.

Comment: I was about to post [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate#comment263615_308875) glad I am not alone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered?tab=mytags

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately it was possible to choose this options before.

Comment: Thanks. That is the same link as Dipen posted in the comment above. I did read it, and am not the only one who use it a lot it seems

Comment: @Sklivvz: Is there a GUI for that yet?