# Proposal: Add a filter "My tags" to all the question lists

Tags: feature-request

When I check the different **Questions** lists (Newest, featured, etc...) without specifying a specific tag, I am flooded with non-relevant (for me of course!!!) questions.

I've got a decent amount of tags.

So I always have to filter the questions tags by tags, by clicking on my own tags list on the right side. This takes time and is not fun. When I am on the mobile app, the experience is even worse.

Maybe I have missed something, but apparently the feature to filter on "All my tags" at once doesn't exist, which is weird considering that it is for me an essential feature for people mastering a lot of different technologies.

Would you consider adding this, or point me to a simple way to do it that I would have missed?

Comment: I don't think you've missed anything. Everybody just hacks around it by creating a search query using their favorite tags, and then bookmarking it. Personally, I use the homepage, which is personalized. Refreshing once or twice usually keeps me as busy as I have time to be answering questions.

Comment: The [new navigation beta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) lets you (set up tabs to) filter questions by (a subset of) favorite tags.  See [How to filter questions based on favorite tags with the new filter tabs](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308882/how-to-filter-questions-based-on-favorite-tags-with-the-new-filter-tabs).

Comment: Well... I've got 3 browsers, 10 computers, 3 different workplaces... the bookmark is NOT a solution. And this is not applicable to the mobile app. Let's hope something arrive soon...

Comment: Works just fine on my machine, I for example never see a [javascript] question in any of these lists.  Not that clear what's going on with yours but I'd guess that you did not actually set the filter yet.  Go to your profile, Preferences, Ignored Tags section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Well... I've got 3 browsers, 10 computers, 3 different workplaces... the bookmark is NOT a solution.

Details about your (beta new navigation) tabs are saved on the server, so any custom tabs you happen to save on one browser or computer will be available on any other browser or computer.

**Can you setup a tab for all your favorites?**

[image]

Yes.  I've done this in the new navigation beta, but I have so many favorite tags (most not shown in the tag field as they're scrolled off to the left in the UI), I find it more productive to setup separate (Swift, watchOS, ...) tabs for specific language or platform questions.

Once you've enabled the new beta navigation, use these steps to create your own custom tag tabs:

1. Select + new tab.
2. Enter a list of tags for that tab.
3. Select whether you want to filter by *any* tags that match or whether *all* tags must match. (This implicitly separates your tags with OR or AND.)
4. Right-click on the tab's dropdown arrow to give your tab a specific name.
5. Click the Save button to make that tab permanent.

**Is there a mobile app solution for this issue?**

> And this is not applicable to the mobile app.

Not sure if Android also does this, but the latest update for the iOS app just added [a way to save a custom filter for questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276115/stack-exchange-ios-app-is-getting-new-question-nav).

Comment: Thanks. My comment about bookmarking was for Cody not you. I was struggling with my preferences following your initial proposal. But this is much more clear. I'll have a look tonite

Comment: [As Hans suggested](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318686/proposal-add-a-filter-my-tags-to-all-the-question-lists#comment319955_318686), you can also use the ignored tags preference (or an explicit AND NOT boolean in your tag list) to cut down on non-relevant questions.  See [examples](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate).

Comment: So I am testing the new custom tab layout for 12 hours and I am happy with it. It clearly addresses the issue I had and give much more flexibility. Thats great