# Notifications for new questions that match criteria

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Are there any plans for notifications of new questions based on specific criteria (tags, keywords, votes, etc.)?

Are there any third-party applications which use the Stack Exchange API that make this possible? http://stackapps.com

Comment: Check out http://stackexchange.com/filters

Comment: Yes, that's in the direction of what I wanted! Keywords and filters based on votes, bounties, etc would still be useful.

Comment: Please give a read to the [tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info) for [tag:feature-request]. You'll need more information about your feature if you want it to be taken seriously.

Answer (score 3):

You are very likely looking for the [new navigation feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing), which is presently in Beta.

To activate it, go to your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202138/bobby) and select "Edit Profile & Settings".  Towards the bottom, there's an option to opt-in to testing the new navigation.  Be aware:  there is a waiting list.

[image]

Once you're in, you can create tabs which filter based on several criterion:

- Tags
- Answered
- Bountied

You can also order things based on vote count as well.  There are a lot of other options in there as well.

Comment: I've enabled "I would like to participate in testing the new navigation" yesterday, but I still don't see "+ new tab" as described here. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318691/5202138. How can I create custom tabs?

Comment: @Bobby:  You have to be a part of the beta before you can observe it.  I'd advise patience.