# Renaming a tab requires an explicit click on the Save button

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-nav

When you try to rename a tab, the change appears to stick, but doesn't really.

I renamed a tab, using the drop-down menu. The textbox appears, you fill in a new name, and hit enter. I thought that'd be enough; I did hit enter after all. But on reloading the page, the tab name reverts to the old name again.

Only after the second such attempt did it occur to me that perhaps there was a separate *save* action to be performed. And sure enough, only then did I notice that the blue *Save* button lights up when you rename a tab. Clicking on the button properly saves the tab rename.

I find this surprising behaviour; hitting enter seemed to rename the tab right there and then. Can tab renames be persisted without having to hit 'Save' all the time?

(I tagged this as a bug because the UI is not working as expected).

Comment: Ok, so I'm [not that crazy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308924/3764814) I guess :-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski or maybe you're just surrounded by crazy people ;)

Comment: Renaming... tabs? I have no idea what feature you're talking about.

Comment: @user2357112 Probably something to do with new-nav.

Comment: An additional mouse click needed? What is this, the Middle Ages?;) (Just kidding, I completely understand the problem)

Answer (score 5):

I'm trying to understand the interaction we want so we can design the best experience possible. Can you help me out?

What should happen if you rename an unsaved tab?

- if we save the whole tab (name and criteria) then it could be weird because the act of rename shouldn't save unrelated stuff
- if we do not save the whole tab, but only the name, then it could also be weird because the name would still show a "*" indicating a dirty state needing save (the unsaved changed criteria)
- if we do not save anything then the behavior would be inconsistent with renaming a saved/clean tab

Furthermore, if you save a tab, then modify it, then rename it: should we overwrite the saved state?

Comment: My two cents: - Option 1 could work because you're *giving a name to something*, so you want that *something* to persist. - Option 2 could be weird because you can inadvertently end up with a tab name unrelated to its contents. - Option 3 is not that bad. If you rename a saved tab, it remains saved. If you rename an unsaved tab, it remains unsaved. So it's consistent in some way after all. :-) I'd go with option 3.

Comment: I think the `*` unsaved indicator was not really clear to me; it took me a while to figure out that it meant that the tab was not yet saved. A tab rename 'feels' like it is a separate, simple action, separate from the rest of the tab state; if the tab itself isn't yet saved, the name change won't need to be persisted yet. If the tab 'exists', save the name change, the tab tags / sort / whatever states still need to be saved separately.

Comment: ..Although the * seems pretty much standard to show that something is unsaved. Seems good (to me) unless there is a better way to show that the tab us unsaved.

Comment: Yeah, at first I thought the `*` just indicated a custom tab, since it showed up for all of my tabs, none of which were saved (to my confusion the next time I visited the site). I think the ability to have "unsaved" tabs at all is a design flaw; just have them be saved with every change. Having the ability to toy with the filters on an existing tab without ultimately saving them seems like it'd only be useful in a few edge cases... like for developers who are testing the filtering/tab functionality.

Comment: Perhaps the `*` indicator would feel better if it'd be on the *right* of the tab title. Many text editors put it on the right, it feels weird on the left.

Comment: What about making the `*` a) a different colour to the name, and b) stay there while you edit the name. At the moment, it looks like I can rename `*foo` to `foo`. In fact, I can! I can call my tab `*foo`, and when I click off, it says `**foo`!

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem here goes beyond when to save, and is with the way the rename UI is implemented:

- it's not editable while you're editing the rest of the tab's information, so it doesn't feel like part of the form which contains the "Save" button
- you have to actively choose to edit it, by accessing a menu item
- you then get an in-place edit box (some 170px away from your mouse cursor, because the rename option is last in the menu)
- to save changes, you click away from this in-place edit box, at which point a * appears, and only then does the Save button activate
- the save button is then several hundred pixels away from the control you were interacting with, or the menu item you first clicked

The whole problem goes away if you stop trying to be clever with inline edit controls:

1. open the tab's menu
2. select rename
3. get a popup text box, next to your cursor, with a caption like "rename as"
4. click "Save Name"
5. the popup disappears, the tab is renamed, and no interaction with saving changes to the tab are implied

Comment: You can also double-click on a tab title to edit it, I guess that's why they made the inline editor.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Huh, I could've sworn I tried that... I still think this is really bad UI though - if clicking away doesn't save, why does it stop being editable? For that matter, the editable mode doesn't even look all that editable - no UI to highlight that this has changed from a label to a text-box, no accept/cancel buttons, just suddenly you're editing the web page. The whole thing smacks of "hey, in-place edits are modern and cool, text-boxes are old-skool; what does UX stand for again?" ;)