# The live refresh randomly starts getting questions without the summary div

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, live-refresh

I am not sure if this ever happened to me in the old nav. But in the new nav, this is randomly coming without the summary divs of the questions.

I was able to grab a screen of that behavior.

[image]

I was able to reproduce this bug randomly. I couldn't observe any specific pattern when this was happening.

Once the summary stops coming, the same happens for the following new questions from live refresh.

Browser: Firefox 38.0.5, OS Windows 10 Pro

EDIT: Here's the code that comes up. The problem looks like the `question-summary narrow` starts loading randomly. Still not able to get a specific pattern.

```
<div id="qlist-wrapper">
<div id="question-mini-list">
<div class="new-post-activity">10 new questions</div>
<div id="question-summary-33390272" class="question-summary narrow " style="display: block;">
<div id="question-summary-33390265" class="question-summary narrow " style="display: block;">
<div id="question-summary-33390258" class="question-summary narrow " style="display: block;">
<div id="question-summary-33390201" class="question-summary">
<div id="question-summary-33390198" class="question-summary">
<div id="question-summary-33390197" class="question-summary">
<div id="question-summary-33390192" class="question-summary">
<div id="question-summary-33390180" class="question-summary">
```

UPDATE: This is still happening on Firefox and Chrome. Not sure if this matters but this seems to happen every time I keep the tab open for a while. The number of questions to be loaded doesn't matter.

Comment: Save the page next time so someone can check if HTML, CSS, Firefox or something else screwed up.

Comment: @nwp Thank you. See my edit. The source code doesn't get updated as the new questions are coming through ajax I think. However I got the inspected code.

Comment: @DipenShah it does, but only if viewed through your browser's developer tools. The normal view-source thing won't show the changes made by JS.

Comment: @rstat1 which is what I am calling inspected code?! (Which is what the edit is about). Generally I right click and select inspect code to open the developer tools and hence the name inspected code.

Comment: Same on chrome 46.0.2490.71 m, but 100% reproducible, I have it each time I click the 'X new questions'

Comment: This has been fixed for me on Chrome for the last 2 days. Try clearing your cache or whatever

Comment: @Sammaye Nope. Tried. still happens. Both on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Hmm I thought it might be something to do with multiple tags but it doesn't happen for me even on php and mongodb combined

Comment: [These](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php%20jquery%20symfony2%20javascript%20html%20jqgrid%20mysql%20sql-server%20ajax%20regex?mode=any) are the tags I am using where it gives me the bug.

Comment: I have it on [tag:r], didn't notice on [tag:chef] and there's not enough activity there to confirm

Comment: Happens also on IE11. Randomly or, at least, not a recognizable pattern

Comment: it would be super helpful to get the web socket traffic when anybody observes that (chrome dev tools \ network \ ws \ qa.sockets.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @DipenShah misunderstanding on my part..sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out we weren't re-subscribing to the new real-time feed on any of the non-selected tabs when you changed your expanded/collapsed layout (which is a global-ish thing).

The repro steps are/were:

- have at least 2 custom tabs with multiple tags (`any` + popular tags e.g. php, java, c# works best)
- go to the second tab
- toggle expanded/collapsed
- go back to the first tab
- wait for new posts

A fix is rolling out with the next build (build rev `2015.11.2.3807` on MSO, `2015.11.2.2924` on sites).

Comment: Would it be fair enough to mark this as status-completed (just pending roll out?)

Comment: sure, was too busy rolling it out :)

Comment: Sorry @m0sa this is still happening in my case on Firefox/Windows 10. I have tried clearing my cache and everything. Exact steps to reproduce in my case: I saved some tags as a new tab (which is locally saved in the browser I believe). I go to http://stackoverflow.com/ and don't navigate to the favorites tab that I created and let some questions accumulate. Once there are some questions to view, if I click on the tab then, this happens. Again this does not happen every time.

Comment: @DipenShah do you even switch the layout manually at all when this happens?

Comment: @m0sa Yes if I switch the layouts the bug goes away but it pops up randomly again. (I just tried again)

Comment: OK the bug I fixed included switching tabs and was reproducable reliably.. So this is something else. Mind sharing your saved tabs? localStorage.newNav

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dipenshah8/fgwent6m/ or direct URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php%20jquery%20symfony2%20javascript%20html%20jqgrid%20mysql%20sql-server%20ajax%20regex?mode=any Try switching back and forth