# Inconsistent formatting when clicking the "load new questions" link in a custom tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

I am enroled in the new navigation testing and I have created a couple of tabs with tags that are interesting for me. I was looking at the questions list in one of the tabs and a *"There are 3 new questions"* notification appeared, so I clicked it to load the new questions.

Then I saw something weird. While the original list had the questions in the "long" format (with a question summary included, and the votes, answers and views counts stacked vertically), the new questions appeared with the "short" format (no question summary, and counts stacked horizontally):

[image]

My understanding is that this is a bug and all the questions should always appear with the same formatting.

Comment: @Oded That was fast. I was editing the question to do the same edit (retagging) as you! :-)

Comment: Already reported: [The live refresh randomly starts getting questions without the summary div](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308901/the-live-refresh-randomly-starts-getting-questions-without-the-summary-div/309339#309339) Given the answer and the comments to it, I'm confused as to if this is _actually_ resolved or if the question here is a duplicate.

Comment: @kendra So far no it hasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).