# New questions in custom list are displayed in the wrong format

Tags: bug, new-nav

Sometimes when I click on the *X more questions* bar that appears while displaying a custom question list the new questions are displayed using the wrong format:

[image]

Note that the format selector in the top right is wrong too: I've actually set to the "expanded", and it's correct for the "old" questions to be shown in the expanded format.

Refreshing the page fixes the issue.

I know that "sometimes" it's not really useful, but I've not been able yet to deterministically reproduce the issue, it doesn't happen always, it doesn't happen often, but it happens quite a bit.

Let me know if there's something I can try to try to narrow it down.

**Update:** Just now I went back to the questions list from a question by clicking the StackOverflow logo in the top left corner and then click on my (custom) list and noticed that the format selector shows a wrong format selected:

[image]

Here too refreshing the page fixes the problem (the selector shows the correct format selected).

**Update:** it seems this issue always creeps up when you go to a custom list from the home page for the first time after passing through the home page.

Let's explain:

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/
2. Click on you custom list
3. Notice that the format selector shows the wrong format
4. Refresh the page
5. Notice that the format selector shows the right format
6. Browse to another page (e.g. *Tags*, *Users*, a question)
7. Go back to questions list by using the *Questions* button in the navigation bar or using the browser's back button
8. Notice that the format selector shows the right format
9. Go back to the home page by either clicking the StackOverflow logo or by manually entering the URL
10. Click on you custom list
11. Notice that the format selector shows the wrong format
12. ???
13. Profit

Note that going back to the home page by clicking the *home* tab does not trigger the issue.

Related issues:

- [Inconsistent formatting when clicking the "load new questions" link in a custom tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309698)
- [The live refresh randomly starts getting questions without the summary div](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308901)

Comment: I've posted a new question since the other two I found are marked as "fixed" and "rolling out" but they are over a week old and the problem still persists.

Comment: I've seen the same issues on the homepage, where there is no format selector.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's the same problem, I think, because the selector it's in the home page too, but it's hidden, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311653/91696.

Comment: Why aren't there hand-drawn circles on those diagrams to draw my eyes to the important part?!

Comment: Question tabs? How do I get them? I've tried searching the meta...

Comment: @PythonGuy: [Opt in to new-nav](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate).