# Questions display format selector missing from the home page

Tags: bug, new-nav

When I'm browsing a custom *Questions* tab I can toggle the questions display format by using the format selector in the top right:

[image]

However when I'm browsing the *home* tab the format selector is not shown:

[image]

However the selector is there: when doing a hard reload it's shown for a moment (FOUC?) and then it's hidden:

[image]

Since the *home* tab uses the format chosen while browsing a custom tab, shouldn't the selector be shown on the home page too?