# Questions showing expanded content

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

I've found a minor bug in the New Navigation on Stackoverflow.

When navigating to Stackoverflow, the main screen shows up with the home tab selected. By default, all the questions are "minimized", that is they appear like in the image below:

[image]

However, once in a while the content will all appear like so:

[image]

Notice I am on the same `home` tab. This doesn't always happen, but I can reliably recreate this bug with the following steps.

1. Click on my `bootstrap` tab (Note: Questions on this tab appear expanded for some reason. They don't on my `laravel` tab.)
2. Click on a question in the `bootstrap` tab.
3. Click my browser's back button (Note: Browser is Firefox Developer Edition).
4. Click on the home tab.

After these steps, all the content appears expanded. If I refresh (F5 or click the logo) the content appears minimized.

Note that this is a very minor bug and has no actual effect on performance, I just found the behaviour interesting.

Comment: Related possibly dupe http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308901/the-live-refresh-randomly-starts-getting-questions-without-the-summary-div

Comment: @DipenShah Similar yes, but your's seems to be mixing the two styles randomly. Mine is loading them all as one or the other.

Comment: Agreed. Although I think its the same thing that's causing these two separate problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Indeed, this has fixed the issue. Only thing I notice now are `*` appearing next to custom tab titles when you click them, that won't go away until the page is refreshed.