# The live refresh randomly starts getting questions without the summary div... again

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, live-refresh

Seeing the same issue that [The live refresh randomly starts getting questions without the summary div](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308901/792066) has, just that in that case it was fixed, but the problem reappeared. Is trivially reproducible, just open some active tag page and wait. Probably related to this [specific change](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312434/792066):

> - the page is pre-rendered on the server, this will eliminate the initial flicker

[image]

Comment: Comments on the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308901/the-live-refresh-randomly-starts-getting-questions-without-the-summary-div#comment266412_309339) suggest the status-complete was applied prematurely.

Comment: @psubsee2003 that is weird, because before [latest changes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312434/792066) nobody noticed.

Comment: I can't repro: steps?

Comment: @EbenezerSklivvze just reproed on MSO "home" tab, just wait for one question to be edited/asked/answered, then click the "X new active post". Added the image to the post

Comment: browser and os? It's *not* trivially reproducible with the given steps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't reproduce it, I just fixed something on the home page that could have generated this issue. I'm marking as completed.

It will be deployed in `rev 2015.12.17.3997` (meta) and `rev 2015.12.17.3103` (main).

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it anymore, so whatever was done, apparently fixed it.