# Slash after questions in URL returning 404 in new-nav

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

In the [new-nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate),

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ returns to a 404 page, where as in the old nav it returns the default questions page. Without the slash the URL seems to be working fine. This is probably the most used URL and is broken in the new-nav. Can this be addressed please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for this is rolling out in the next build (build rev `2015.10.27.3789` on MSE/MSO, `2015.10.27.2908` on sites).