# What creates the "explore our questions" tag?

Tags: support, new-nav

In the new-new nav, there is a box above all questions on the home page that looks like this:

[image: Explore our questions]

What populates this list? Only one of these is a tag I'm interested in. One I have explicitly ignored.

Is this list static for everyone or is it using some data from my history to populate?

Comment: Related ["feature request" answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308964/4320665) on main question about new nav

Answer (score 2):

I see the same tags.  If you notice, those are the 10 [most popular tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular).  Based on two data points (you and me), I think it's just a static list of those top 10 tags.

If you ignore the special [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) which only moderators can assign, the same is true for meta.  [Most popular tags on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags).

> [image: Explore our questions meta]

Comment: `s/static/dynamically measured/`