# Allow the tab to also be "default"

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

In the new navigation tabs, there are several customizeable options. However, regardless of the level of customization, when I click "Questions" it no longer returns to the selected tab I was on. It used to, but no longer.

Perhaps there are too many options to figure out what was last used, and so it defaults to just creating a new tab "newest*". While I understand the historical precedence of showing `newest` by default, I also in this age of customization want to dictate that default.

[image]

When clicking "Questions" instead of returning to a new "newest*" tab, I would like to return to the selected "default" tab.

- Clicking on "Questions" brings up the default tab
- Only one default tab may be selected at one time
- If there is no selected default, then return to the new "newest*" tab functionality

Comment: Alternatively just set the default tab to whichever is the left-most one, and let the "home" tab be moved/renamed by users. Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308890/2756409

Comment: Home has a different functionality though, it is tied to the site logo link, and is associated with the "interesting" search result. It has always been that way, and I think people expect that functionality to be there. I am not requesting a change to clicking the logo, removing the home tab, or altering the home tab. I would just like to make it so that when "Questions" is clicked, the default tab is navigated to. I believe this makes sense, it is very annoying to reach the preferred tab otherwise, and often when I, and others I assume, want to refresh the current tab I click "Questions".

Comment: I usually just hit F5 or click the refresh button on my browser, if that's what you mean.

Comment: F5 will not navigate to the default search if you are not already there for example. So if you are viewing a question (like this one right now), and you click questions it will take you to the newest tab regardless of setup. And then you must find the preferred tab and click on it in order to reach that search. At that point, you may hit f5 on the keyboard or refresh on the browser, but the functionality that was also available previously was the ability to click questions to reload the content you were seeing. That was my point, clicking questions should get you to the selected content.

Comment: I second this. I don't like that clicking on the "Questions" button creates a new "newest" tab that I end up deleting each time.