# Navigating to Questions recreates "newest" tab

Tags: bug, new-nav

The new tab system is great and I quickly set about creating custom tabs to speed up finding relevant questions. One of those steps was to delete the generic 'newest' tab. However, I've now noticed that if I navigate back (via the Questions link in the top right) a new 'newest' tab is created.

*Custom tabs with no newest tab*
[image]

*Navigating back recreates it (note unsaved state with the asterisk)*
[image]

I'm not the only one seeing this behaviour e.g. [see this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309039/allow-the-tab-to-also-be-default#comment268933_309039).

Looking at this I can see that it is caused by the link to `/questions` being the link used for the newest tab. I guess the solution to this would be to allow a default tab to be defined and change that link to `/default` (or change `/questions` to point to the default and create a new `/newest`).

Comment: I hate having to delete the "newest" tab every couple of minutes