# Tab-based nav remember last tab

Tags: feature-request, new-nav

For the custom-tab based navigation (at this point I gave up trying to figure out what "new nav" refers to, so, see screenshot):

[image]

Would it be possible to make it remember the last tab you clicked?

I find I use the following flow very frequently:

1. Click one of my custom tabs looking for questions to answer.
2. Visit a question, often browsing around from there (e.g. viewing related questions, getting distracted by the HNQ, etc.).
3. Then when I want to go back to the list to look for a new question, I click "Questions" in the nav bar.

When I do this it resets back to "newest" each time, but it'd be great if I could just pick up right where I left off with the last active tab already selected.

Smoothest workaround at the moment is to right click the back button (in Chrome), and go back to the question list from there (noting that I'm usually 2 or more links deep at this point).

Comment: Related [Allow the tab to also be "default"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309039/allow-the-tab-to-also-be-default)

Comment: Weird that no huge amounts crying out for it. This would save myself few clicks in a second, moreover, I'd lose my focus later.