# Different Question counts on Votes tab and Active tab

Tags: support, new-nav

If you go to `Votes` tab it shows (9,976,233) Questions which is lesser than the count that is shown by `active` tab (10,421,421). In both the occasions filter is selected as **All**. This can't be due to caching since theres a huge difference. Is there another logic in showing this number?