# Moving the tabs left or right does not trigger the save button

Tags: bug, new-nav

As noted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309063/576767), when moving tabs right or left, reloading the page will put them back to their original position.

An easy workaround is to add a tag, remove it, then save, which will keep the new position of the tab. Or to remove the 'disabled' class on the save button, if one really does not want to add a false tag. Is this intended?