# new-nav: Can we get "favorite[ question]s" as one of the available tabs?

Tags: feature-request, new-nav, bookmarks

I expected to find [my] "favorites" as one of the available tabs in "Where are my tabs?" but it's not there.

This would be a nice improvement, as I frequently favorite (aka "star") something just so I can quickly get back to it.

That "quickly" is relative -- navigating to my profile, maybe changing to a different tab, finding Favorites, maybe switching to "newest" view and then finally clicking the top one would become a lot easier if it was just another tab on the home page.

As mentioned in several comments, the "favorite" term is heavily overloaded. Straightening out the terminology (say, to label these questions as "starred" instead) is outside the scope of this request, but might be a good thing to consider as well.

Comment: Also here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308921/874188 but not a separate question, just feedback on [tag:new-nav]

Comment: Note that "favorites" is ambiguous, while "star" is not; stars are only applied to questions, while "favorites" usually means "favorite tags".

Comment: Yeah, that's why I added "aka starred"; though the term in the profile is consistently "favorites".

Comment: Yes, let's have that!

Comment: @KyleStrand Stars also apply to chat messages. I would specify "favorite questions" or "favorite tags", this question *obviously* being about the prior.

Comment: @TinyGiant Ah, didn't know that. I agree this question's intent is obvious, but I also think the change to the title is a big improvement.

Comment: Also noted here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268787/245360

Comment: @PatrickHofman No, that question is about favorite *tags*, which is why I made a point of clarifying the distinction in my comment above.