# Custom tabs don't roam across clients

Tags: bug, status-deferred, new-nav

So I set up some custom tabs on my work PC. Awesome. I log on to a different PC, and I've got none of the custom tabs I set up - this is unexpected behaviour, if not a bug.

Answer (score 27):

This was noted as a "known issue" in [the latest release notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate):

> Deep linking to tabs is currently handled client-side

This should be fixed in a later release, once the desired behavior for the UI is nailed down.

Comment: I really think it would be better if release announcements/notes were made in the same form that they are for all other software, rather than buried within the Q&A model here on meta.

Comment: There are probably good arguments for that, but... Right now they're linked to from the option that enables this test... *and every page on the site in the sidebar.* I don't think we can make them easier to find.

Comment: It's very hard to find, say, the release notes for two versions ago, isn't it?

Comment: Considering you can't *use* two versions ago...

Comment: That's not relevant if you're looking for information/known issues with a new feature that was introduced two versions ago and hasn't changed since. Not every line of code changes in every release. It is common practice in the software industry to post a list of release notes alongside version number in chronological order on a "releases" page, for easy access to any of them.

Comment: I believe that if an issue hasn't changed since, the same issue would be listed among the latest release notes. If there are other, older unlisted issues you can think of then that would definitely resolve any questions we have about the effectiveness of using meta for this purpose. Fortunately, the latest release notes are pinned to the top-right of every SO page and at the very top of that meta post, it links to every update about navigation improvements. So (at least with the current version), no it's not hard to find the release notes from two versions ago.