# Pluralizations!1!!1!! bugs ons thes homepages

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, plurals

The new navs brings the plurals problem.

> [image]

Comment: -1: nots enoughs plural.

Comment: [careful there...](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266499/typo-in-the-new-post-activity-div-on-so-and-title-on-other-se-sites

Comment: @Dip OK, but the nav has been [updated since](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate?cb=1) :) and now, it's invalid to post the bug reports about new nav on MSE because it only functions on SO and MSO (it was with the previous version of new nav, which was active on MS[E|O] and SO).

Comment: @nicael I am aware of the update about the new-nav. However there was no change made to the `new-post-activity` div apparently.

Comment: The name of the game is "new questions" and there is exactly one in that category. Next.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, yes, we've been lazy pluralizing all the new strings lately. A bunch of those should be fixed in the next build (build rev `2015.11.11.3857` on MSE/MSO, `2015.11.11.2970` on sites)