# Click-and-drag tags to search bar

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, new-nav, tag-search

It appears that the [new nav release candidate announcement question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308875/1858225) is no longer active and that [feature requests are now being asked as new questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/new-nav%20feature-request?mode=all), so I am copying and pasting my feature request (originally posted as an answer on the announcement) into a new question.

### Summary

Since you can click-and-drag tags (dropping them into a text-field pastes the tag URL there), it would make sense if the tag-filter search bar automatically recognized tag URLs and converted them to tags.

### Pictures!

When you do this:

[image]

You currently get this behavior:

[image]

... this looks like a bug, but it's not too bad; clicking on the tag-search bar again cleans it up to look like this:

[image]

... but the filter doesn't actually work in this state, and you can't save the tab this way.

Here's what it *should* look like:

[image]

Comment: this is not really [tag:new-nav] specific.. same happens when you drag the tag to the to right search box, and FWIW the markdown editor (where it should be converted to a tag magic link) and comment editor. We omitted drag&drop functionality in the initial release of new nav on purpose, since it's not a paradigm we support elsewhere - keep in mind that there are things that would work more organically with drag&drop, like tab reordering.

Comment: @m0sa That's true, but the tag search bar used for the new navigation page is the first UI element that I've felt is really impaired by lacking this feature (though admittedly I've never learned the syntax for tags in the markdown editor). This is because (1) it's a search bar that can only search for tags, and (2) there's no way to auto-populate a query with your favorite tags, so drag-and-drop seems like it should be an easy solution.