# Draggable tags in the new navigation

Tags: feature-request, tags, new-nav

This post is about the New Navigation Release Candidate:

I think there should be draggable tags, which you can drag to a "Search for" or "Ignore" space next to the search bar. After the tags are dragged into 1 of the spaces, it should disappear(when tags pile up it gets messy). Maybe the user could choose which tags go below the search bar(refer to picture). I personally think this would be easier than typing:

```
"[tag] [tag] [tag] not[tag] not[tag] not[tag]"
```

And when you search, sometimes every word you type just turns into a tag, which is a bit of a pain.
I basically want it to look like a neater version of the following image:

[image: How it should be]

Rather than how it is currently:

[image: How it currently is]

The tags used most should appear below the search bar, whereas the tags used less should be in some sort of drop down menu, or the user should be able to choose which appear on the tag pane below the search bar.

This question is very similar to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313759/click-and-drag-tags-to-search-bar), but it *is different*, because I am recommending the spaces to drag the tags, and that one should not be able to type tags in the search pane.

Comment: So what is the criteria for first 5 tags?

Comment: @SagarV The tags shown in the post are just random tags that popped into my head. I think the tags should be automatically set as the most popular ones, but the user should be able to change the tags to fit their preferences. Or they can be favorite tags, most searched by the user, or something else along those lines.

Comment: All new-nav development is currently on hold, there are no engineers assigned to the project. More's the pity.