# Can the new navigation's boolean filters do "A and B or A and C"?

Tags: support, new-nav

With the new nav, I can do more complicated tabs such as "[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)". However, for the longest time I've had a "[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metaprogramming)" *and* another tab "[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [template-metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-metaprogramming)". I'd rather combine these two tabs.

I tried to do "[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [template-metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-metaprogramming) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metaprogramming)", but this doesn't work because it doesn't accept the extra [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). The system also doesn't seem to be able to accept parentheses, so "[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and ([template-metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template-metaprogramming) or [metaprogramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/metaprogramming))" doesn't work.

How can I get the effect of "[a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a) and [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/b) or [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a) and [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)"? Or is it impossible?

Comment: I compulsively want to rewrite this `A and (B or C)`...

Comment: @meagar but does it use weak or strong `and`?

Comment: Related: [Filter Questions that have one of multiple tags and don't have all of multiple tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337714/filter-questions-that-have-one-of-multiple-tags-and-dont-have-all-of-multiple-t)

Answer (score 11):

I believe that the new navigation suffers from the same limitations as regular search.  Attempting to perform `A and (B or C)` or its variant in standard search did not allow for results to show up in the way that I wanted them to.

It may be worth putting this in as a bug report.

Comment: It's probably [meta-tag:status-bydesign], though. Maybe this should be a feature request.

Comment: Not sure about that one, although you might be right...it doesn't make much sense to me to offer a *limited* variant of boolean search, though.  There could be limitations to the system.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Jsleshem:  By stating that, due to the belief that the new nav is built on search, and because search cannot perform the tasks that Justin wants, it's unlikely that this will work and that a bug should be filed, I feel that I have answered the question.  Is there something else you were looking for in this answer?

Comment: @Makoto makes sense. I would have personally left that as a comment, but leaving it as an answer works too.

Comment: @Jsleshem:  You don't ever want to answer a question in comments.  Just don't do it, man.  Answers live longer than comments.

Comment: [[meta-tag:status-bydesign]] because [[status-cant-be-arsed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350909/drag-able-tags-in-the-new-navigation#comment483193_350909)]