# Real good questions that are unanswered

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I have read before now on Meta about unanswered questions but I just want to revisit it and share what is on my mind.

I so noticed that nowadays there are so many questions being asked here and there that some real good questions go unanswered. Some questions barely stay on the `latest questions screen` for 30 seconds. So, I want to suggest that a bar or something of sort should be on every page displaying quality questions, maybe questions that have being upvoted and still not answered and also, a bar on a page with similar questions that have gone unanswered. This I think will help answer lots of questions and help limit good questions that go unanswered.

Note: This bar should be for unanswered questions only.

It is just my thought.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is the weekly incarnation of the meta meme _"I have to wade through so much crap to find questions actually worth my effort"_, and you're asking for things that are already there. The front page _does_ mostly show unanswered questions, and there's always the custom tabs in which you can create a "no answers" list.

Comment: If you can't see the custom tabs option, it's because you haven't opted-in to test the new nav. I recommend it; it's nifty. If for some reason you don't want to opt in, you can always use [advanced search options](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to get what you want. You can also share links to questions on social media if you want to help people see it.

Comment: @BSMP: What "new nav" are you talking about?

Comment: @NicolBolas - [This new nav](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate). The option to get it is in your Profile > Edit Profile & Settings > Preferences at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 5):

The homepage already does this.  Higher scored questions tend to show up higher on the homepage, and having lots of upvotes on the answers (meaning it is already answered well) makes it show up lower.  There are of course other factors, such as whether the post matches tags you're active in, is in the favorite/ignored list, how long it's been since there was activity on the question, etc.

Comment: I've heard this rumor before, never once saw any evidence of it.  Even the "Hot" tab viewed when not logged-in has lots of downvoted questions.

Comment: @HansPassant There are lots of variables, and score is just one.  That doesn't mean that you never see downvoted questions, it just means that they'll spend *less* time on the homepage than an upvoted question.  You probably would see almost entirely upvoted unanswered questions *if there actually were a lot of upvoted unanswered active questions*, but there aren't.  There tend to be a handful, but most good questions tend to get good answers fairly quickly, pushing them off the homepage.  So really you see the *least downvoted* recently asked unanswered questions.