# Can we make the tabs draggable?

Tags: feature-request, design, new-nav

As of now, you can only move the tabs by clicking `Move Left` or `Move Right` on the drop-down of the selected tabs. It can be quite frustrating when you have multiple tabs and you have to re-select the tab over and over again until it goes into the right spot. It seems easier to just drag and drop the tab whereas needed for convenience.

Can we make the tabs draggable so they can change their positions faster and more efficiently?

Comment: yes please! this would be amazeballs

Comment: Obviously everyone else understood this question, but I don't. *What* tabs are you talking about?

Comment: @CodyGray See this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate