# Could we get a better way to see my favorite tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

When I go to Stack Overflow, there are a few tags that I want to focus on. Right now, they're shown on the right side in a column and underneath some other content. This makes them hard to find. I would really like to be able to show my favorite tags at the top of the Stack Overflow UI when I log in, so I don't have to go hunting for them.

Comment: Try the beta new navigation option - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate

Answer (score 1):

As @Paulie_D mentions in the comments, the solution is to try the new page navigation which makes it so much better! [Go to your profile setting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences)s and check "I would like to participate in testing the new navigation."

Comment: Can you add an image of that - or can we easily opt-in and then opt-out again at will?