# Problems with "New" tags tab

Tags: support, new-nav

My understanding is that, in the question list, the tabs at the top (Newest, Active, Votes, etc.) serve to sort data, not filter it.

However in the tag list, I clicked on "New" and then searched for a tag and didn't get a result because it's not a new tag. So it seems this "New" tab is filtering results as well as sorting them.

This seems counter-intuitive to me; is it a bug or expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the tabs at the top (Newest, Active, Votes, etc.) serve to sort data, not filter it.

Those you mentioned sort, but others (Featured, Frequent, Unanswered) filter.

Same story under Tags: some tabs are for sorting (Popular, Name), some are for filtering (New). This is also consistent with the behavior of Users page where Reputation sorts them while other tabs, including New users, filter.

New tags use the same time window as New users: 45 days.

All things considered, the navigation works as designed. This does not mean it should not be re-design, though - after all, we have a [New Navigation Release Candidate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308875).