# Weekly Summary Email of Unanswered Questions By Certain Tags

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice if I had a weekly summary email of unanswered questions by certain tags, where I could click them to see if they're still unanswered, and offer an answer if I knew one.

So, for instance, I could flag "2Checkout" and "PHP" (boolean AND) and then offer my answer. Perhaps I could setup multiples.

Note, however, that at least I can make bookmarks like so:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php+2checkout

...but that doesn't do a boolean AND. Instead, it does a boolean OR.

Comment: Can't you use a [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D++%5B2checkout%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) `[php] [2checkout] answers:0 closed:no`

Comment: It seems like searching for them when you actually wanted to do something would be far less frustrating than getting an email at a fixed time then coming to it later and potentially finding that many of them are no longer unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your feature request seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Here's how you could resolve the bookmark issue, to avoid needing a weekly email.

Your bookmark URL gets rewritten like so:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php%202checkout?filter=need-answers&mode=any

Notice that the boolean OR results from the `mode=any`.

If you change `any` to `all`, the tags will use a boolean AND as you desire:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php%202checkout?filter=need-answers&mode=all

*If you're using the [new navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate), you can even save that filter as a tag, so it's always available.*