# Unanswered questions combined with tag exclusion not working

Tags: bug

I am trying to get a list of unanswered questions which are tagged with **ios** but not tagged with **swift**. The URL which Stack Overflow constructed for me is:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ios+-swift

Stack Overflow appears to be recognising what I want to do. On the right-hand side it says:

> 1,389,194 questions with no answers
>
> tagged with
>
> ios not swift

It just doesn't filter the list of questions correctly. I seem to be getting **all** unanswered questions, it seems no tag filtering is being applied at all. However, if I omit the "exclude swift" condition, it works:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ios

Comment: Works for me in the new nav http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios%20not%20swift?filter=need-answers&sort=votes&mode=all

Comment: @braiam that URL matches zero questions when I try it

Comment: Because you are not using the new nav.

Comment: I have the same issue. And the new nav is closed for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect this to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) for the old navigation. Either opt-in for the [new nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) or use [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) instead:

> [`[ios] -[swift] closed:no answers:0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+-%5Bswift%5D+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0)