# Recommended tab with minScore= 0 does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed

This question is just to report that the "recommended" tab with `minScore=0` does not currently work. It hangs for a while and then respond with an error page.

https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&minScore=0

Here's a screen shot of what I see:
[image: Screen shot of error page]

And these are the response headers that I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 20 Jun 2016 12:45:05 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 20 Jun 2016 12:44:05 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid: feed11b1-5cdc-434f-815e-192b36698c02
Content-Length: 28362
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 20 Jun 2016 12:44:35 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-bma7035-BMA
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1466426644.887331,VS0,VE30224
Vary: *
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
```

Comment: For me, it redirects to the SO homepage (http://stackoverflow.com) ...

Comment: Ok? For me it doesn't. Not from an incognito window either.

Comment: Is the recommended tab something on the old nav? I have the new nav and see "Home -  Voted - Active - Newest"

Comment: @BSMP I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean that.

Comment: @BSMP the nev-new is still in beta, so I assume there are still users using the old navigation style

Comment: I'm talking about the [new navigation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing) that allows users to create custom tabs. I just checked the site in a different browser and I do see different tabs so I'm guessing "Recommended" is on the regular nav and that's why Glorfindel and I are just getting a redirect instead of an error.

Comment: @MårtenWikström there is a new navigation style in beta.  You can see the lastest announcement in [New Navigation Release Candidate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate)

Comment: I see. Thanks for sharing. I'm not using that (yet). :-)

Comment: Yup, definitely something very odd going on; have an idea... trying it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be working now; sometimes, the database just does crazy stuff, and the only way to convince it not to is the magic "don't be crazy" flag, aka `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)`

Comment: Nice and fast work! I can confirm that it works for me too.