# Error message when using new navigation pagination

Tags: bug

It's easy to run into an error message from the pagination used on the [new navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate), as follows:

Starting on page 1, with 15 questions per page:

[image: Step 1]

Select page 5 (for example:

[image: Step 2]

Then decide you'd like to see 50 questions per page:

[image: Step 3]

Suggest that in this type of scenario that the last page (page 2 in this case) should be shown, rather than an error.