# Sponsored tags not aligned well with ordinary tags

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, design, sponsored-tags

As you can see in the picture below, the tags [firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase) and [firebase-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-security) don't align with each other.

[image]

This problem seems to be specific to sponsored tags, since ordinary tags align well with other, while other sponsored tags such as [pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pycharm) also share this problem.

I'm using Safari 9.1.2 (11601.7.7)

Comment: Gotta love `vertical-align`

Comment: how do you get those tabs? i want that very much

Comment: @nhouser9 Hope [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCL86.png) can help you. See also [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate).

Comment: Gotta love this misalignment. @nhouser9 Did you try the "new tab"?

Comment: @sunqingyao awesome! thanks

Answer (score 12):

I have tested with 5 other browsers, none of which show an issue.

Given this is a very small UI issue effecting only one browser on a single platform (and which has a very small market share on Stack Overflow), I am declining a fix, as our time is better spent on higher priority bugs and feature requests.

Comment: But... but... it's off by a pixel! :(