# Can we control the secondary sort on unanswered questions?

Tags: support, feature-request

When I select "Unanswered Questions", the results are presented sorted by votes. Is it possible to sort by Newest or otherwise control the sort order?

To clarify, I am doing this on Stack Overflow, after filtering for [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) questions. First hearing of "New Nav". I will look into that.

Comment: *"When I select "Unanswered Questions""* Where? I can only filter for "no answer" and that can be re-sorted.

Comment: Are you using the old nav or the [new nav](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate)?

Comment: Apparently using old since I never set it  to new (did not know it existed).  I will pursue that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Tiny Giant's suggestion, changing to the [New Nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) did the trick. It took me a moment to find the sort order menu to the right of the tag list, but this does everything that I wanted.

Comment: Does this still apply and does it apply to everyone? The closest I could find under preferences was "Navigation > disable stickiness".