# Why isn't there an Unanswered button in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, design, unanswered-questions

On most Stack Exchange sites, there is an Unanswered button on the top of the page:

[image]

However, on Stack Overflow, there isn't any Unanswered button:

[image]

Stack Overflow seems to be the only site where this happens. On all other sites where I have an account (MSO, SU, MSU, MSE) there is an Unanswered button, and before asking this question, I randomly looked around on some other Stack Exchange sites to see if this button existed there, and it did.

Why is Stack Overflow almost the only site, if not the only site, that doesn't have any Unanswered button?

Comment: This button bar has two SO-specific buttons (Jobs and Documentation). It would become far too wide on SO if it included these buttons alongside the "unanswered" button (though I recall seeing it back when Docs was in private beta).

Comment: Two theories:  the amount of unanswered questions would overwhelm folks, and if one really wanted it, they could leverage [the new homepage navigation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) and get unanswered questions that way.

Comment: We used to have it. They took it away after adding Documentation. Doesn't matter now; the new top bar doesn't have it, either.

Comment: @dorukayhan Really? You think another 100px is what makes that grouping 'far too wide'?

Comment: Maybe rename "Documentation Beta" to "Docs" so we can fit unanswered? :)

Comment: @dorukayhan It would actually fit. I made [a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNe8e.png) in Paint which shows how it would look if there were an Unanswered button. As you can see on the picture, there wouldn't really be any problem having it.

Comment: That docs button is such a waste of space.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We have a much wider tabs thing than most sites, because of Jobs and Documentation:

[image]

And anyway, the unanswered tab is still there, albeit in a different place:

[image]

Answer (score 30):

On the new design it's here:

[image]

Under the "Where are my tabs?" link:

[image]

Where, as it says on the pop-up, you can create and save your own custom tabs.

Comment: What can we do if we have clicked "Got it. I don't need to see this again." but, later on, *do* want to see that screen again? The "Where are my tabs?" link disappears if we click it.

Comment: @TylerH there's a checkbox in your preferences.

Comment: @Braiam Thanks. Seems like it would be better to just leave the "Where are my tabs" link there indefinitely. A quick, obvious way to bring those preferences up.

Comment: I just discovered how to activate it. In Edit Profile & Settings -> Preferences -> New Question Filter there's a checkbox "Opt me in!" that has to be checked.