# Support favourite tag combinations

Tags: feature-request, tags, bookmarks, tag-watching

Favourite tags are cool, but there are cases, where I'm interested in a tag, but only when it's paired with a specific other tag, for example I'd like to have a favourite query for tags [realm][android], so [realm][swift] is not matched.

I'd love to see favourite tag **combinations** on this site.

Comment: That would also help to address concerns such as this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370121/361842; great idea

Answer (score 2):

We can accomplish the same thing by editing the URL, and then save the link with your favourite bookmark method.

For example, I am often interested in [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) questions specific to [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), so I could use the link:

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba+excel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba+excel)

...to list all questions that have both the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) **and** [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tags.

Then it can be customized with other parameters, such as `?sort=votes` to sort by votes.

---

I keep them all together in a folder on my Firefox toolbar :

[image: img]

Comment: It is worth noting that the now unshipped / sunset / retired *previous* [new nav release candidate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate) had a feature to organize and store the tag combination the /questions page. When that was disabled those that still used it had to fallback to the bookmark method you describe. Currently that is only feasible way.