# Merging the [excel-vba] into [vba] - speak now, or forever hold your peace

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

> #### The plan - two-month implementation timeline
>
> The biggest concern raised here was that splitting [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) would make it difficult to watch, as there's currently no support for watching/favoriting tag combinations. The DAG team has a plan to address this over the next couple of months ([announcement on MetaSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer)); once they do, it will be possible to split these sorts of "tag combos" without undue disruption for current subscribers.
>
> UNTIL THEN, I'm doing the following:
>
> 1. Ensuring that all questions tagged [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) are *also* tagged [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) except in cases where this would push the number of tags over 5
> 2. Adding a warning to the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) and [excel-vba-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba-mac) tags to encourage askers to add both [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)
> 3. Adding a warning to the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag encouraging askers to specify an application tag as well.
>
> After analyzing the current set of questions in these tags, I've come to believe that the critical blocker here are questions where *multiple* applications are involved: for example, Excel *and* Access. It simply won't be possible to correctly tag these until we can get rid of the combination tags entirely, so we'll have to bite the bullet on that as soon as possible.
>
> The warnings are live now.
>
> I'll be adding tags to just shy of 35 thousand questions today, and revisit the split once the system allows.
>
> ---

---

This particular debate has gone on a bit too long...

- [Duplicates dichotomy: [excel-vba] vs [excel] + [vba]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356057/duplicates-dichotomy-excel-vba-vs-excel-vba)
- [Tag editor extraordinaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288749/tag-editor-extraordinaire)
- [User on tag-edit spree for 2+ days... [excel]+[vba]=[excel-vba]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364745/user-on-tag-edit-spree-for-2-days-excelvba-excel-vba)
- [Synonymize / rename [excel-vba] and others to [excel-automation] / [excel-activex] / [excel-objects] / [excel-object-model]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/synonymize-rename-excel-vba-and-others-to-excel-automation-excel-active)
- [Merry Go Round Situation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305546/merry-go-round-situation)
- [OK to fix Excel VBA tags programmatically instead of manually?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370092/ok-to-fix-tags-programmatically-instead-of-manually)
- *more...*

IMHO, there's no value to having a hyphenated tag here; two tags work just as well to represent the topic's scope while also allowing much more flexible filtering and combining with other tags. I'd like to just be rid of it, with a four-step process:

1. add the [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag to all existing [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) where it is currently missing
2. merge [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) into [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)
3. synonymize [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) with [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) (alternately: blacklist this tag with a warning to use separate language and application tags)
4. add a pop-up warning for folks selecting the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag asking them to also specify a specific application tag when relevant.

This process could also be applied to other *application-*vba tags as well.

This is gonna mess with some folks' tag preferences; that's unavoidable. OTOH, if I'd done it a year ago it'd have messed with about 8K fewer people's preferences, so putting it off longer isn't fixing that situation.

Can anyone think of any good reasons *not* to do this and be done with the endless confusion and debates?

No debates about whether Excel is a programming tool, please; in the real world, people write applications in Excel - deal with it.

Comment: @Shog9 Finally! Good job on that one. ♥ After all those pointless debates and arguments I personally think it doesn't matter which option we go for in the end (one tag, both, synonym etc). As long as it's **consistent** throughout the entire site, it's fine in my book. Nothing worse than ambiguities.

Comment: There seems to be quite a history of rancor with this, so fixing it is definitely a step in the right direction in my opinion.

Comment: Having 2 tags instead of 1 will *always* mess with tag preferences, since you can't favourite combinations of tags.

Comment: That... Was the problem we were trying to solve with New Navigation, @Dukeling - hopefully we still will.

Comment: Just to make this a tad bit more interesting. How about we also add the commonly misconcepted `[macros]` tag into the mix as well. As per: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256623/what-to-do-about-macros

Comment: @Luuklag - [tag:macros] as had a long standing warning not be associated with MS Office 'macro recording' or [tag:vba] sub procedures but TMK it never got the the one-repper 'warning' not to use it. It is also commonly confused with [tag:macos] to the average dyslexicly challenged..

Comment: Anyone in favor of [tag:excel-vba] and other similar tags ([tag:word-vba], [tag:powerpoint-vba]) should be in favor of introducing the following tags: [tag:nodejs-javascript], [tag:browser-javascript], [tag:wscript-javascript], [tag:jquery-javascript] -- different applications hosting the same language with different libraries.

Comment: To reverse the discussion: Do we want a `unity3d-c#`, `wpf-c#`, `net-core-c#` tag? I don't think so. I do not have any domain knowledge of `vba`, but it sounds like `vba` is the language, while `excel` is the library/hosting application. I don't see any difference to  `unity3d`.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Except it's closer to creating a new project with the VS WPF C# template, which has some references added by default, and those references could not be removed. Also, the runtime environment exposes some of the types in these references as global objects, not requiring an explicit `using`.. This engenders the perception that a particular environment configuration is a new language, or at least different dialect of VBA. (Not what I think.)

Comment: **The `excel-vba` tag is gone**. See [Status of removing the Excel-vba (and similar -vba) tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399177) for what happened.

Answer (score 160):

An [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) question in meta? It's always nice to be reminded that we're still a part of the Stack Overflow community!

As for burninating the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag, please no! As anyone who knows [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) will tell you, there are **immense** differences in syntax between [word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba), [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba), [powerpoint-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-vba), and [outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba) - before answering any questions, you have to know what parent program they're writing from!

If *anything*, the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag doesn't mean much, for just as I've mentioned - without knowing what the parent program is, you can't write a successful subroutine. A majority of [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) is working between Microsoft programs (like creating PowerPoint presentations or Word documents from Excel).

(I would support only creating the pop-up warning to specify what program they're writing out of for the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag.)

Comment: So am I reading this right, essentially: "please don't do this! Unless you can do what you said you'd do in the question"? :-P

Comment: @TylerH *Precisely!* :) It was meant to be a passive vote for option #4!

Comment: So is excel-vba a misnomer?  Is it really _not_ VBA and would a layman who knows VBA but not Excel-VBA not be able to answer this (analogous to Android and Java questions)?

Comment: @Makoto Excel-VBA is a proper term - it *is* VBA, however, someone who knows "general VBA" may have no idea how to write in Excel-VBA. I wrote in Word-VBA for a year before transitioning to Excel-VBA, and while I was fluent in Word-VBA, I had quite a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: So...this is more the unfortunate situation that Excel-VBA is in because it's so similar to something else but so very, very different - again, drawing parallels to Android and Java which was thankfully disambiguated very early on.

Comment: Well, VBA is the same between programs, they just use different object models from each other.

Comment: @Makoto Ah I see - I'm not familiar at all with Android or Java, but I'm sure it's the same scenario.

Comment: Just to be clear: the numbered list is the steps I'll take if I go through with this, in order, not a set of independent options. I kinda don't think the status quo is tenable - we're closing in on 20K questions that are *probably* about excel-vba but aren't tagged excel-vba, with at least as many questions tagged [excel-vba] that aren't even tagged [excel]!

Comment: @Makoto You can think of excel VBA as VBA with an Excel library of functions already loaded, and access-VBA as VBA with an Access library of functions already loaded.  You can write VBA without *any* of the MS application's loaded, and run it as a stand alone thing, but that makes up a tiny percent of VBA development; most is using at least one of them.

Comment: @Servy:  Got it.  That makes it crystal clear for me now.  In that case, Shog's approach makes the most sense since it would also add the warning for users to specify the library they care about when writing VBA.

Comment: @Servy If I reading everything right, we can talk about the differences between excel vba and access vba in the same vein as C and C++?

Comment: @Braiam No, it's like talking about the difference between using C++ to write a web app versus using C++ to write a desktop application.  You're using exactly the same language, you're just using it with radically different libraries that radically change the types of things you're using it to do.  C and C++ are not "the same language but with different libraries".  There are fundamentally different language features and behaviors.  Excel and Access VBA are the same language, with the same compiler, but with different linked libraries.  It's also just a pretty bare bones language.

Comment: Adding to this, it also means that if I want to ask a question about, say, Word-Vba, under the new system I would have to use two of my tags to do this.

Comment: Note that there is a _common VBA_, and a lot of simple questions can be answered without any application-specific code. Questions like _how do I convert a `ParamArray` to a normal variant array_ to _how do I call this WinAPI function that requires a GUID struct as a parameter from VBA_ can be answered in common VBA, and should be applicable to all different applications. While tagging the application on questions relevant to it is a good idea, we shouldn't be over-eager to discourage tagging questions just VBA.

Comment: I was having this discussion with another user. My initial stance was that I thought having Excel-VBA was useful in that it would allow greater specificity. I could search for questions that involved VBA in Excel ***specifically***.  The notion being, I could avoid Excel in general, and VBA applied to other non-Excel environments. And yes, so I would be prepared for the syntax and object model required. This is all based on the tag being correctly applied. So I am definitely in the camp of a pop-up/guidance for useful tagging over scattergun tagging.

Comment: @Servy - Sure, *'You can write VBA without any of the MS application's loaded'*. I can think of two languages off the top of my head (PowerShell and BV-Script).The main reason I can come up with those on such short notice is that he questions are often cross-tagged with [tag:excel-vba] because they don't understand the intricacies and are looking for assistance from someone who does. Where are you going to send those requests when [tag:excel-vba] gets lumped in to a homogenized [tag:vba] tag? Seems like it is just a bigger pot to try and swim out of.

Comment: @Jeeped I wasn't advocating for one tagging method over another, just responding to an inquiry over the nature of the differences between different usages of VBA. That said, what you're saying is that people often find it useful to see questions asking about other application's uses of VBA because they're often able to answer them, even though they're primarily using a different application's object model, and you're using the fact that people often can answer those other questions as a reason to keep the questions separate, rather than having a single tag for them?  How does that help?

Comment: @Servy - no worries; I think we are close to the same page on that.

Comment: @ale10ander You still have 3 tags to work with... is that not enough?

Comment: @QHarr Note that even after such a change as this is implemented you can still search for questions that have both tags by searching for `[excel] [vba]` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel+vba

Comment: Not sure why this gets so many upvotes as it seems @dwirony has misunderstood the OP... :)

Comment: **There are no differences in syntax between VBA hosted in Excel and VBA hosted in other applications.** The **entire** difference is 1) which libraries are referenced by default, and 2) which objects are globally available. Keywords, syntax of method calls, syntax of property usage, operators are all the same across the board for all VBA environments.

Comment: @ZevSpitz that's not quite correct. `Option Compare Database` and the special syntax for drawing lines in Powerpoint come to mind. But that's basically some rather obscure edge-cases that are relevant for maybe 0.001% of [tag:vba] questions

Comment: I don't like having to tag my questions with both `excel-vba` and `vba` just be sure everyone catches it. I'm fine with just `vba` especially with the pop-up urging the user to select the application...but *not* to require it, since some VBA questions may really be app-independent

Comment: @TylerH Thanks. I have been given a schooling on tagging. I didn't really know how tags combine in search. Now more _au fait_

Comment: _If anything, the [tag:vba] tag doesn't mean much, for ... without knowing what the parent program is, you can't write a successful subroutine._ I would suggest that the parent program is virtually irrelevant -- what is far more salient is 1. the target object model, and 2. the task at hand. Also more important than the parent program, is that 3. the program is being written in VBA, and not in C# or Python. The fact that the VBA is hosted in Excel is a distant fourth behind these other 3.

Comment: @Jeeped _Where are you going to send those requests when [tag:excel-vba] gets lumped in to a homogenized [tag:vba] tag?_ Those posts will get to [tag:excel]+[tag:powershell], or [tag:excel]+[tag:vbscript]. Tagging questions that have nothing to do with VBA (e.g. manipulating Excel data in Powershell) with a tag that refers to VBA, strikes me as rather odd.

Comment: There are no syntax differences at all.  Syntax is cast in stone by the programming language, VBA.  The only difference is the object model, each Office product has its own.  With lots of overlap, there is always an Application object, there is always a reference to MSO and VBE.  Documentation is very similarly laid-out.  Not being able to discover this is a regretful side-effect of only ever looking at [excel-vba].  Big fat waste, not just of SO help, you are also putting pointless restrictions on personal career opportunities.  Discovering this is one of the SO contributor goodies.

Comment: @HansPassant _there is always an Application object, MSO and VBE_ This is true of the Office object model libraries, but there are other libraries that do not have an Application object (e.g. ADO, MSHTML, regular expressions, WMI). It seems to me that trying to make any distinction between Office libraries and other type libraries is rather arbitrary -- I can equally well add a reference to either kind of library and use its types.

Comment: VBA is also used in non-microsoft products. Their object models are freakishly different than the MS object models. The code style is so radically different that you need the API manual to get anything done because most functions return their result to ByRef parameters instead of the normal function return path. That being said, VBA is the same. I can update code written for these bizarre APIs because I understand VBA and sometimes a VBA Q&A written for Excel helps you with some totally unrelated software.

Comment: What if having `excel-vba` encourages people to use it when they're not sure their question is not Excel-related, but VBA only is concerned (beginners, who have the most questions, are usually confused about that). What if `excel` and `vba` only available separately made them consider what they are asking about? That's how I interpret this question.

Comment: Indeed, there are several differences between VBA for different applications, which is why combinations [word]+[vba] should be used

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of these, but how does it compare to `OpenXml` for excel vs word vs ppt? I've used it with word and excel and it also seems vastly different.

Comment: @emsimpson92 The emphasis in OpenXML is extracting information from the document, be it a Word document, an Excel spreadsheet, or a PowerPoint presentation. The object models under discussion work from the standpoint of automating an application and its component parts; this includes windows, toolbars, and of course documents and document parts. Another significant difference is that OpenXML is only accessible from .NET languages, while these object models are available from any Automation-supporting language / environment (which includes .NET languages on the desktop Framework).

Comment: So if there was **no difference in syntax** between (open office) star basic and vba, they would "be the same language" as vb6 (historically, the other big VBA language)? Interesting, but irrelevant point of view. access-vba and excel-vba cover different problem domains

Comment: My vote here is to keep the excel-vba tag; as mentioned it is much more specific than the vba tag alone and gets the attention of a huge audience out there who's main calling card may be doing wonderful things with excel and vba together.

Comment: @david There are syntax differences between OO Basic and VBA, but more -- VBA can make use of Automation libraries while OO Basic cannot. But since [tag:vb6] can use Automation libraries just as [tag:vba] can, and -- as you say -- they both have (virtually) identical syntax, they are indeed the same language. _access-vba and excel-vba cover different problem domains_ Or, the Access and Excel object models each cover different problem domains, which may or may not overlap with the VBA problem domain -- the Access object model is the same problem domain whatever language it is used from.

Comment: @T-Heron The OP's proposal is not to merge everything from [tag:excel-vba] into [tag:vba]; the proposal is to retag everything with [tag:excel-vba] with the two individual tags -- [tag:excel] and [tag:vba], which is equally specific as [tag:excel-vba].

Comment: @HansPassant Isn't the point of the tags to help people interested in the topic to find it, and to help people not so interested to avoid it?  Nothing stops someone from being interested in `excel-vba` and `access-vba` both, but if I've done all my career development in `excel-vba` and nothing in `access-vba`, having them merged to vba would just show me a lot of annoying, irrelevant `access-vba` questions.  It is certainly true that 99.9% of the differences are in the libraries, but that's also what most of the questions will cover.

Comment: @RyanLundy [tag:vba] and [tag:excel] are no different than any other language / API tag pair. Someone whose developer history only includes C# and WPF, and who follows the [tag:c#] tag, will be presented with many irrelevant (to him) questions about ASP.NET MVC, .NET Core etc. Yet no one would argue that each possible tag pair should be a new tag, especially since [the tag pair can be searched for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+wpf); and the SO plan is to eventually allow multiple-tag bookmarks on the sidebar.

Comment: Your tl;dr seems at odds with your longform answer. Your tl;dr says no but your longform answer says yes.

Comment: @TylerH To be honest I didn't even write that TL;DR - someone else edited my question with it. I don't even know why it was necessary, my post wasn't terribly long. I'll remove it.

Comment: The last line of your answer -- _If you're able to create the pop-up warning to specify what program they're writing out of for the vba tag, then that has my vote!_  -- combined with the first two comments, could be understood as supporting the split if such a prompt could be added. That's why the TL;DR was added. TBH I suspect that many of the upvotes on your answer made the same mistake; otherwise, how is it that the question (in support of the split) is as highly upvoted as your answer (against the split)? (ping @TylerH)

Comment: @ZevSpitz No - you are misinterpreting my post... The OP was about burninating the tag `excel-vba`, which I am not for. To me, a post tagged as `excel` and `vba` doesn't not constitute an `excel-vba` post. If a post is tagged as `word`, `excel` and `vba`, which program are they writing from? If I can't tell from their question, then I can't help them. I think you're over-analyzing this.

Comment: @TylerH I make myself very clear that I am **not** for the burnination of the `excel-vba` tag. My long form answer doesn't mean I want posts tagged as `excel` and `vba` - I would still need to see `excel-vba`.

Comment: _If a post is tagged as word, excel and vba, which program are they writing from?_ Why does it matter? If the question is about manipulating Word objects, then the answer should describe which properties / methods / objects in the Word object model to use. If the question is about manipulating Excel objects, then the answer should relate to the properties / methods / objects in the Excel object model. The host is a virtually irrelevant side detail, since the specific code under discussion can target either object model from any host.

Comment: @TylerH the tldr wasn't at odds with the rest of the answer, both said the same thing: keep the excel-vba tag and add a tag warning to vba. I wrote the tldr because people was interpreting the same thing as you did, the complete opposite.

Comment: @Braiam Where have I said even once that I want excel-vba removed? The third sentence, and the first real line of my post reads exactly as **"As for burninating the excel-vba tag, please no!"**. I am **NOT** going to edit my post and *assume* that 100+ people simply misinterpreted it - I'm leaving it exactly as is.

Comment: @dwirony [you just responded to someone that made that mistake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace/370101?noredirect=1#comment605637_370101): Your tl;dr says [do] no[t burninate] but your longform answer says yes [burninate]. It's critical to be very explicit in meta.

Comment: @Braiam My post was clear, *your* TL;DR was confusing - I didn't even understand your verbiage. The post stands on its own just fine.

Comment: Your post could be misinterpreted as _As for burninating the excel-vba tag, please no! ... [however] If you're able to create the pop-up warning to specify what program they're writing out of for the [tag:vba] tag, then that (i.e. the entire OP) has my vote!_ The same interpretation is in the [first comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace?cb=1#comment603507_370101) which you strongly confirmed in the next comment. Perhaps you should just clarify that you only support the prompt, not the entire split.

Comment: What @ZevSpitz said. My tldr got the two things you wanted to [not] happen very clear: leave the [excel-vba] tag *alone*, add the tag warning to [vba]. If Shog interprets it as if you are supporting removing [excel-vba], he *will* do it. Remember, this post was started by him, and when you have a hammer, everything seems to be a nail.

Comment: @Braiam From [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace/370101?noredirect=1#comment603521_370101) it seems that Shog9 didn't misinterpret the post.

Comment: @Braiam wrong, if you see my clarification comment (the first one) I ask if that's what the case is and OP says "yes precisely" in response. So we have it straight from the horse's mouth, so to speak, that I am correct. OP seems to have contradicted this yet again in the comments so perhaps the whole answer should be rewritten to clarify their position. Either way I think the position is not a very good or clear one.

Comment: @ZevSpitz FWIW I downvoted this answer because it's not coherent in what it recommends.

Comment: @TylerH which is why my tldr, which ignored your comment and went straight for the qualifier "It was meant to be a **passive vote for option #4!**". BTW, now Shog is going forward merging the tags...

Comment: @ZevSpitz is funny how we are all speaking right pass each other interpreting stuff as we see fit, and even Shog wasn't free of being misinterpreted (read the commentary of the revision).

Comment: @Braiam In this particular case it leads to really strange results -- both the OP and this answer are very heavily upvoted while also heavily downvoted, even though their positions are contradictory -- the OP is pro-split, while this answer is against. Where are the 168 upvotes on the OP reflected in the only 25 downvotes on this answer, and the 158 upvotes on this answer in the only 32 downvotes on the OP?

Comment: @ZevSpitz power makes might, and it seems that the dissenting popular opinion will not be taken into account, for *reasons*. I prefer this solution because is the less disruptive and allows us to soft-solve the problem. My ideal solution is to remove [excel] and separate all the on-topics involving excel in very specific tags, since we already have excel* tags for most of them.

Comment: @Braiam As someone who agrees with said _reasons_ ([VBA is an orthogonal domain to any of its object models](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/869358); host application is irrelevant to organizing questions, unlike the target object model; newcomers can learn to tag [excel]+[vba] as easily as [excel-vba]; the [UI for multiple-tag bookmarks in the sidebar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370430) is scheduled to be fixed [sometime this summer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312041/300504)) I cannot say I am terribly heartbroken. _this solution_ is not really a ...

Comment: @Braiam solution, but rather a preservation of the status quo. [vba] can't be gotten rid of; but neither can [excel], because newcomers (to StackOverflow, or those whose first experience in programming is the Macro Recorder) cannot be expected to deal with the fine differences between [excel-automation], [excel-worksheet-functions] and [excel-data]. My ideal solution would be to limit [excel-vba] to programmaticaly controlling Excel objects, whether from the Excel host or another host/language/environment, and rename/synonymize it to [tag:excel-automation] (which is a thing, BTW) or ...

Comment: @Braiam ... something similar, and leave [tag:excel] for newcomers; but [that idea was already heavily downvoted by the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/synonymize-rename-excel-vba-and-others-to-excel-automation-excel-active)..

Comment: @ZevSpitz In my optimal scenario, my solution heavily favors those that answer questions. Since they don't have to deal with tag combinations, they can decide what specific questions about excel they would like. Newcomers would be forced to select the specific tag and not using something generic. For me only certain aspects of excel are on-topic, since general excel questions (how to insert a bar graphics, kind of questions) aren't on topic.

Comment: Even if this answer had 200 upvotes and 0 downvotes, I doubt Shog would have refrained from moving forward unless *new evidence/arguments* were brought to light. This and all the other answers against just rehash the same argument that has kept us in the cycle for years no. And btw, @Braiam let the confusion of the tl;dr serve as a lesson in restraint when editing others' answers.

Comment: @TylerH the tldr was out of respect of the author. [This on the other hand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/324221/revisions) (revision 2) was done without an ounce of respect for the author. That kind of edit, I would never agree with it, which alters the meaning (and the intent, since you like to use that word) of the post. Mine kept the original meaning (and intent) and tried to clarify it.

Comment: @Braiam pro-tip, if you want to respect authors, don't write tl;drs for them that contradict what they've said in various places. Stick to comments and let them provide the clarification.

Comment: @TylerH again, where's the contradiction? What you say that the post said? Remove [excel-vba]? No. The [author already said that's not what they wanted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace/370101?noredirect=1#comment605662_370101) My TL;dr was exactly the same as the longer post, more explicit.

Answer (score 102):

[I asked about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62868/150559) on Meta Stack Exchange back in 2010. As a result of one of the answers, [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) [word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba), and [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba) temporarily became tag synonyms of [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba).

About a year later, these tag synonyms were removed and Joel Spolsky [explained why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110909/150559). He said:

> There is a difference between Excel questions (which concern
>   worksheets, mostly), VBA questions (which concern a programming
>   language used by several Office apps), and Excel-VBA questions (which
>   concern that programming language used in the context of Excel, the
>   Excel object model, etc).
>
> They are three different things, and not every question is about all of them.
>
> Making excel-vba a synonym for VBA was an abuse of the synonym system,
>   so that synonym has been deleted. The result was that people tagged
>   things excel-vba which was silently changed to vba, and we lost
>   information in the process.
>
> Using "excel" and "vba" tags on Excel VBA questions is not appropriate
>   if the question isn't really about using Excel or programming Excel
>   worksheets.

[excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) is one of the tags I'm most active in. Not all of the people asking questions there know whether or not VBA is required to solve their issue. This can result in tags being applied fairly haphazardly.

For me, [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)[vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) is an acceptable replacement for [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba). The long history of disputes about these tags suggests, however, that it would be wise to get more input from the active users in these tags before making changes

Comment: This is good background info, thanks! There are ways around the silent retagging issue if we go that route; regardless, what we have now is the same unholy mixture of tags we had 8 years ago, but 100x larger, so worth keeping this up for discussion long enough to solve it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot agree. [tag:powerpoint-vba] is one of the only places you will regularly see Select or Selection as a legitimate answer while the practice is actively discouraged in [tag:excel-vba] and other mediums. [word-vba] depends heavily on cursors and position markers that are completely irrelevant anywhere else. [access-vba] again has similarly named functions as other [tag:vba] platforms but are implemented and react in very different ways. The list goes on and on.

Comment: First thing I do when I see someone using a select statement is link to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: @Luuklag Technically a `Select` method call.

Comment: Spolsky can't have an impartial view on the matter, he was the one that designed the first Excel object model.  It is his baby.  He blogged about it, fun read: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/

Comment: @HansPassant The quote from Spolsky is relevant to synonymizing [tag:excel-vba] to [tag:vba] in isolation. Shog9 is proposing adding the [tag:excel] tag before creating the synonym; there would be no loss of information in that case.

Comment: @Jeeped Isn't that a function of the underlying object models? The same advice (e.g. use `Select`/`Selection` from PowerPoint, not in other apps) applies to the PowerPoint object model vs Excel/Word object models, whatever language they are used from. But the intention here is not to tag with only [tag:vba], but with the pair of tags [tag:excel] and [tag:vba].

Comment: @ZevSpitz - Sorry, but you're not even close to the direction the xxxx-vba regulars take to advance the learning curve of neophytes to the whole programming game.

Comment: @Jeeped Did you mean to comment here? I'm sorry, but I don't see what your last comment has to do either with the answer, or my previous comments.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I believe his comment was intended - and to further elaborate, you're generalizing the Microsoft applications while to Jeeped's point, the regular xxxx-vba contributors tend to differentiate them all drastically. Even though `Select` *works* in Excel, it is **taboo** to recommend its usage - to the point where users are immediately redirected to a page to read about [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: @ZevSpitz, you are mistaken.  Currently people who see `excel-vba` are people who are interested in Excel VBA.  If it's split into `excel` and `vba`, people will see those questions who are interested in any area of Excel, or any area (or app) of VBA.  That will broaden the audience...but it'll only increase the number of people who will see questions that aren't relevant to their interests.  How can this be an improvement?  Until SO has a way to save intersections of tags as favorites, this will most definitely cause a loss of information.

Comment: @dwirony _Even though 'Select' works in Excel, it is **taboo** to recommend its usage._ Absolutely, but this is because of the Excel object model being used, and irrelevant to VBA. A Python programmer working against the Excel object model will be told to avoid `Select`, while a Python programmer working against the PowerPoint object model will be told to use `Select`. _you're generalizing the Microsoft applications_ Absolutely not -- programming against [tag:excel] is very different from programming against [tag:powerpoint], whether in VBA, C#, or any language; and irrespective of host.

Comment: @RyanLundy _loss of information_  isn't quite accurate -- the question is still tagged with both tags. Especially since this information can already be used to search for [questions that are tagged both `excel` and `vba`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel+vba). You are correct that since currently in the UI you can't bookmark pairs of tags, having this tag is a convenience, but that needs to be balanced against the confusion caused by multiple tagging strategies.

Answer (score 62):

The language is [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba). Whether you write it hosted in [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word), [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access), or [sage300](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage300), [autocad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autocad), [solidworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solidworks), or any other one of the 200+ possible VBA host applications out there (it absolutely *isn't* just an "Office" thing), it's still VBA.

IMO the **language** to tag with should be [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba).

Then there's the main **object model library** you're using. Note that an Excel/VBA application can very well (and a lot do!) reference the Access, Word, or PowerPoint object model libraries too.

I'm with the crowd that wants to see [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) split into [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)[excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel). "Excel-VBA" just contributes to conflate "language", "host application", and "type library", and that confusion cannot possibly be a good thing.

Someone with a [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) question should tag their question with the relevant object models their code is referencing (be it [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word), [adodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adodb), or all of these - as relevant to the question), and the body of their question should make it clear what the *host application* is - otherwise readers can safely assume that a  [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)[excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) question involves code that's hosted in Excel.

See I can write a piece of VBA code in Word, reference the Excel object model and have a problem with the Excel part of my "Word-VBA" code - it's critically important that the question mentions the code is hosted in Word, and uses the Excel object model. Ideally the code itself should make that clear, but VBA makes it easy for such things to be implicit in the code, and impossible to tell just by looking at a snippet in a SO question (e.g. unqualified `Range` calls could go either way).

If the question doesn't involve code that specifically uses types and methods defined in the Excel type library, then a tag like [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) is actually harmful, since it potentially hides a question that could be answered by folks that know VBA, but aren't familiar with the Excel object model. Same with [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba), [word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba) and all the others.

I therefore fully support the proposed solution:

> 1. add the [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag to all existing [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) where it is currently missing
> 2. merge [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) into [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)
> 3. synonymize [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) with [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)
> 4. add a pop-up warning for folks selecting the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag asking them to also specify a specific application tag when relevant.

...as long as it applies to all [vba-appname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba-appname) tags.

Comment: Meanwhile, any COM connected language (not just VBA) can run specific object models. I have run Access/Excel methods in Python, R, even PHP!

Comment: But then you'll have the problem that people who post will NOT add two tags, meaning we'll have to do a lot more tag editing AND asking people what application they're using.

Comment: @Parfait and many Python questions dealing with the Excel libraries frequently tag with [tag:python] and [tag:excel], just like many [tag:c#] questions do. I'm failing to see how [tag:vba] should be any different.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon ... agreed. We should make a note that VBA is a just layer like other languages. In fact, it is the first default checked item under Tools\References! It has nothing to do with actual Office app.

Comment: @Parfait correct. It just so happens that the host app's object model can't be removed from project references (ditto with the VBA standard library) - that said Cindy has a point: it does put a bit of a burden on us veterans to ensure tagging is done properly... but then, what else is new? ;-)

Comment: Also, the VBA standard library isn't VBA *the language*, it's just *the standard library* - conflating language with library is pretty much like saying C# is the `System` namespace.

Comment: This is a common but very narrow view of a programming language. Yes, c is a small language of only 32 keywords, which does not include an IO capability, so the iconic hello-world program is "not really c". Or, alternatively, Excel VBA is a programming language which includes language elements for manipulating spreadsheets. FWIW, the latter was the point of view of the designers of Excel VBA: by design it was an extensible language. And the former was the view of the designer of c: by design, the language did not include the system library.

Comment: What about naming the tags so they expressly reference the host application?  `vba-in-excel` + `word-automation` for VBA code running in Excel to automate Word, using the Word object model?

Comment: @cxw `[vba]`+typelibs is all that matters. The host application merely determines what type library is referenced by default (and can't be removed), on top of the VBA standard library - that's entirely covered by `[vba][excel][word]`, assuming the OP isn't just a code dump without any context or description... which would be an unclear question regardless of the tags. Also, `[vba]` being the language, it needs its own language tag - also "hosted in Excel" is completely irrelevant for 99% of the `[userform]` and `[web-scraping]` VBA questions. VBA is a full-fledged language, full stop.

Comment: @david _Excel VBA is a programming language which includes language elements for manipulating spreadsheets._ Except that those same elements can be used equally well from Access-hosted VBA or any <app>-hosted VBA. Why then should these elements be defined as part of the language, instead of elements of a referenced library?

Comment: Splitting `excel-vba` into `excel` and `vba` means that anyone interested in `excel` will see the question, and anyone interested in `vba` (with any Office program) will see it.  A rather small intersection of these people will actually be interested in VBA for Excel, rather than VBA for another program or Excel for another reason.  The tags don't find things by intersection; they're an OR, not an AND.  Splitting the tags will lose focus and annoy people.

Comment: @RyanLundy split tags works very well for every other language tag on the site though. Splitting the tags will contribute to educate the many folks that seem to think "Excel-VBA" is a language. Your last contribution in the VBA tag was almost a decade ago (btw kudos for a 4-digit user id!!)... I monitor the VBA tag on the daily, and I'd need to follow a bunch of confusing "host" tags to see everything VBA just because people don't understand that the language is VBA and that's the only language tag they need to use. 95% of VBA code is written in Excel anyway, there's no focus problem.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yet it's very disruptive to the answerers.

Answer (score 19):

The biggest concern I have with this change (which I think I *otherwise* agree with), is the Stack Overflow UI.

I am probably one of many people who, while not being a primary VBA programmer, have some expertise in using VBA in Excel (and only Excel). I don't know the language well enough to answer hard questions about VBA in general; but I do have some specific domain knowledge in using it with Excel. As such, I'm interested in seeing Excel VBA questions from time to time, and answer a few of them.

If the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag went away, that would be much harder for me, simply because of the UI of Stack Overflow. I'd have to do a custom search (i.e., I'd have to type out my search criteria), rather than clicking on the tag in my favorites section.

If the UI were improved such that you could have saved searches in the left nav, say, and not just purely tags, this wouldn't be an issue, and I'd simply create an [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)[vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) search and be done. But since it's not, this change will mean I don't look at Excel VBA questions anymore. I'm not interested in VBA in any other context, and I don't care *enough* to make a bookmark in my already full browser bar or to type it in the search box.

I suspect that a lot of other users will *also* end up having this problem - not just users like me, but newer users; they won't know about searching for multiple tags, so they'll either pick one of the tags and browse it (and you'll end up with the [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag being the *de facto* [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag, most likely) or they'll not browse at all, losing some of the audience.

So - improve the UI, get custom tag combinations into the left nav, if you want this to work *well*.

Comment: "If the UI were improved" 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the problem with the proposal.  People who were interested in `excel-vba` won't have a good way to say so anymore.  If they put `excel` they'll get _all_ Excel questions, and if they put `vba` they'll get _all_ VBA questions.  And soon they'll get annoyed and quit answering questions because so many will be irrelevant.

Comment: To address this concern, I've been active on various excel and powerpoint vba tags for about 2 years now. My (albeit workaround) solution is a bookmarked search with each of these tags selected. It's not as neat as actually following tags, but it gets the job done

Answer (score 18):

Apart from the issues already mentioned regarding differing syntax between Office applications, the other thing to consider is that VBA is actually used outside Microsoft Office too in various CAD/CAM applications for example.

Whilst the core language is the same across all applications there are a vast array of object libraries that affect how VBA has to be used within an application and so the various `*-vba` tags do in fact serve a purpose and are not just synonyms.

That being said, in the interest of being fair — I personally see no issue in having [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tags instead of a single [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag on a question. Additionally, having the tags in this manner would probably increase responses on questions because for the most part VBA developers have a good understanding of Excel in general, and a lot of VBA questions can actually be solved without VBA *(Whuuuut??? I know, right!?)*.

That's only going to work if the whole culture around these tags shifts, and if I'm being brutally honest — I don't think anyone from SO will win that battle.

If anything, I think the effort would be far better spent helping people understand that VBA, VB and VBScript are **not** synonyms and make some of the question tags a bit cleaner.

Comment: Sorry, but I see an issue with not having an [tag:excel] and a [tag:excel-vba] tag together just as I see an issue with not being able to put an [tag:excel] tag and a [tag:excel-formula] tag together. There is a natural hierarchy here that defined the broad spectrum and then narrows it down to a certain degree. It doesn't have to be narrowed down to the nth degree but worksheets and the VBE are different platforms and should be recognized as such. After all, isn't the point of these tags to attract a focused audience or is it really just white-hat search engine optimization?

Comment: btw, kudos on bringing he whole [tag:vba], [tag:vb.net] and [tag:vbscript] confusion into the conversation.

Comment: @Jeeped Yeah I agree and prefer to have both tags, just in the interest of a balanced argument I’m saying I wouldn’t see it as the end of the world if it _had_ to separate tags.

Comment: Wait, you think educating people on the differences between `vba`, `vb.net`, and `vbscript` is *easier* than splitting a tag into two already-existing tags? With this change, people simply won't be able to tag stuff as `excel-vba`. They will only have `vba` and `excel`. From where I sit the only real harm is going to come from tag following (people will have to adjust their followed tags until new-nav functionality comes back, if ever), and people will have one less tag to use, but 3 tags should still be plenty.

Comment: To my knowledge, you are the first person who has expressed that [tag:excel-vba] refers to the Excel object model; the obvious perception of this tag is the intersection of Excel and VBA. Now, if it was called something like [excel-object-model](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/synonymize-rename-excel-vba-and-others-to-excel-automation-excel-active)...

Comment: @TylerH I don't think it's easier, particularly as a lot of people who make that mistake are newcomers to `vb*` language(s) - I'm just saying that if we're going to spend time and effort in an attempt to "tidy up" this group of tags that we might get more bang for our buck there. As I mentioned, it isn't going to ruin my day if the `excel-vba` tag was split out, but I don't think SO will ever win the community round to agreeing with it anyway, so place the effort elsewhere if that makes sense?

Comment: There actually is an [tag:excel-automation] tag, which if I understand correctly, is supposed to represent the Excel object model.

Comment: It's a mistake to describe _different syntax between Office applications_ as if there are multiple languages between the various applications. The language is the same (except for a few deprecated corner cases) across all applications; it's only the available object models that are different.

Answer (score 13):

One case that isn't covered in your question is [excel-vba-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba-mac). 
As there are severe limitations in the functionalities of vba on mac, for obvious reasons ofcourse. And therefore requires a different mindset when programming for [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos) environments, because you lack a lot of basic functionalities present when programming for [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows)

According to your suggestion one would then tag a question with [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) + [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) + [macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos), leaving room for only two aditional tags, compared to the room for 4 tags when using the hyphenated [excel-vba-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba-mac) tag.

Now I don't immediately see a problem here, as I believe there is rarely a need for more then two tags that described the question content besides its environment. But I do think this is something we need to keep in mind.

This is also the case for [word-vba-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba-mac)

Comment: I completely agree. I regularly edit [tag:excel-vba] tags to [tag:excel-vba-mac] in order to attract a more focused audience. There are simply too many disparities to throw them together.

Comment: FYI [tag:macros] has nothing to do with VBA, in a rather explicit way. See tag info.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon are you refering to my answer or to my comment on the OP?

Comment: Oh damn, nevermind, I totally read "macos" as "macros".

Comment: The thing is, VBA doesn't need a Mac-OS mirror tag for every host application. Most major differences between VBA on a Mac and VBA on Windows pertain to VBA itself, not the host application or its object model. Very good point bringing up Mac-OS, but IMO there's no need for a Excel-VBA-Mac tag when VBA-Mac would do just fine. i.e. tag your "Excel VBA MacOS" questions with [tag:vba-mac][tag:excel].

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, That indeed is true, would be wise to add a generic `[tag:vba-mac]` tag, question is however, how are (new) people going to find that tag, as it isn't completely natural when adding tags. Adding all the singular tags is more natural behaviour, so we need some warning if someone adds both `[tag:vba]` and `[tag:macos]`

Comment: @Zoe, I don't see why not. As it obviosly states: "macOS-specific behaviour" which is the case why vba on mac works different then on windows.

Comment: @Zoe except, running VBA on a Mac changes how file I/O needs to be written, reduces the number of available type libraries (e.g. can't use Scripting Runtime i.e. `Dictionary` and `RegEx` classes, to name a few).... knowing that VBA code needs to run on a Mac is a fundamental piece of information that absolutely affects the possible answers.

Answer (score 12):

I'm at odds that with all the bluster about not being rude and welcoming newcomers while an effort moving toward the homogenizing all the flavors of [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) is receiving so much support.

A good percentage of the folks asking their very first question in [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)/[access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba)/[word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba)/[powerpoint-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-vba) are doing so with recorded code that they are trying to improve themselves through self-learning.

Why make it harder for them to find a solution? A pair of [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tags will get them where the most help is available just as [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) and [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba) will do in another situation. If they can figure out that part, I'd say they were 50% done and for the most part, the altruistic 'regulars' bend over backwards to offer assistance.

The problem with a homogenized tag is in its own definition. I don't have fancy statistics for you but I've been working on a nice virtual reality graphic I think you'll enjoy.

[image]

Comment: Besides the fact that Access doesn't offer a macro recorder, this answer is excellent, and the graph should make the decision clear for everyone.

Comment: I went a little broad in my definition of 'recorded code'. I should have expanded it to include 'copied and pasted from the Internet'. However, thanks for grasping my implied meaning in that these new-comers are actually trying (enthusiastically) to write something they can call their own (with a little help).

Comment: So why do you think a new user is going to be able to figure out to tag their question with [tag:excel-vba] and [tag:excel], but not [tag:vba] and [tag:excel]?  Why is the former easier for a new user to understand than the latter?  It's worth noting at this point that, if the proposed synonym were to be added, they could actually tag their question using the first two tags, and it would simply end up looking like the latter two tags when done.

Comment: The only thing I can offer is that as they type [tag:excel], [tag:excel-vba] may present itself in the suggestions. Same with [tag:vba]. Failing both of those, there is the off chance they actually did some on-site research and hit [ask a question] when within one or both of the tags so it may be familiar. Someone coming around for the second time has almost assuredly had their original question's tags modded. I do believe I qualified my statement with *'If they can figure out that part...'*.

Comment: Simply put, your're asking for an answer I do not have; am I to assume that every one-repper using [tag:excel-vba] is an experienced parasite who knows how to bypass the system currently in place? I would prefer not to degrade this conversation to that level.

Comment: Agreed Jeeped, Has someone who picked up any type of programming (starting with VBA for work reasons) in the past years and with MUCH help from SO, although simple one of the things that helped me make a transition from looking online for excel macros to understanding the connection between the programming language and the "macro" was the fact that the `excel-vba` exists. IMHO most of the question that I've seen(from first time users) in `excel-vba` are from business background people with no clue what is VBA that would post question with only the `excel` tag and macro on the title.

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu Would prompting the user to enter [tag:vba] when he's entered [tag:excel] have helped you?

Comment: Even though I support the idea, -1 for taking me for an idiot whose vote you can buy with a silly picture.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, possibly, but due to the lack of understanding I at the time (and new users that come from business background) if it isn't big, flashy, bold and worded along the lines of `This is MACROS writing for Excel` I wouldn't connect the dots. Something that at the time confused me (before realizing in the tag that excel was connected to vba), was that although I dabbled with recorded vba I knew it as Macros (blame MS on this one ^^), some excel-formula solution would advise to do it in vba which was something completely unknown to me.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, This to say that unfortunately beginners don't always know this and unless specifically stated, even if stated in tag description, they'll miss it, which besides the inconvenience of re-tagging, might demotivate new users (you know how the community behaves at times), this mainly because the entry point into `excel-vba` is not always programming but business necessity and curiosity.

Comment: Just trying to understand -- if there never had been an [tag:excel-vba], would you argue for its introduction, because absolute beginners should have a one-stop tag? And presumably the only reasons why [tag:excel-vba] deserves such a one-stop tag vs other library/language combinations, is because the entry bar for Excel VBA is lower than say WPF and C# (owing to 1) the macro recorder, and 2) VBA is easily available from the main Excel application)?

Comment: @ZevSpitz, I'm not saying I'd advocate for [excel-vba] if no such tag existed, what I'm stating is that there (IMHO) would be more to clean up (and more confusion) if it didn't, I'm sure you can imagine a lot of [excel]+[macro] tag combinations ^^ (could this combination be stopped if the user doesn't add [vba]? or a pop-up?). And yes, I don't think you simply stumble into Visual Studio and go at it, or at least I had to inform myself to make that step.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, Further more I can see that what you are saying has its merit and makes sense, but shouldn't the question be, would it hinder or benefit the community (and new users)? It seems that the top users of the tag are divided on preference of tags, some argue for logic others usability(?), one thing is certain it seems hard to gauge the full impact without making the changes, but then what? could it be reverted?. BTW why does [<app>-vba] exist in the first place?

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu While the single tag is easier on new users, there is a cost for non-beginner users (probably a far larger segment of the community) in that there are now two tagging strategies for such questions. Posters have to decide which strategy, followers have more tags to follow, reviewers have to choose, sometimes leading to retagging wars; and Meta is full of questions by people who have to make these decisions.

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu _the top users of the tag are divided on preference of tags_ The upvote/downvote ratios on this proposal would seem to imply that the community is heavily in favor of the split. Also, the answers in favor are all highly upvoted with relatively few downvotes, while the answers against are highly downvoted or split between upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu This tag might be considered harmful, as it perpetuates for slightly more advanced users the myth that the Excel object model can only be used from Excel, when in fact it can be used from any VBA environment, and from any Automation-supporting language / environment. For example, this answer talks about various _flavors of VBA_, but adding a reference can convert one so-called flavor of VBA into another.

Comment: @ZevSpitz so, people that doesn't get affected by the brunt of the consequences are deciding whenever they do an action that would affect the folks answering the questions... is this politics?

Comment: @Braiam - sorry to say but you got it right. This is a dog & pony show in the worst sense; nothing more than a perfunctory exhibition of democracy while having nothing to do with the best interest for those actually  involved. Shog9 just wants to piss on something so he/she can put their name on it. Starting up this rat's nest was just the start. It provides notoriety. The site will move through those four steps quickly and without hesitation; I'm sure of it. They couldn't fix a a single spelling mistake on a single web page  within '6-8 weeks' but I'm sure this is a done deal.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, I agree with some of your points, but those same points could be used to argue that all [<app>][vba] tag combinations should be turned into [<app>-vba]. Well.. when you say _The upvote/downvote ratios ..._ that's just not true, all that means is that the meta community is in favor of the solution and not that the tag community is, actually the highest voted answer clearly states _As for burnicating the excel-vba tag, please no!..._ and goes on to add, if we can replicate similar functionality by _...create the pop-up warning..._

Comment: @ZevSpitz and this seems to be the most appealing proposition that meta has, replicate a similar functionality to the current tags by making all [vba] and [<app>] and [<app>]+[*] unto a pop up fest (is this the best design?). Further more when you state _flavors of VBA_ you completly miss the point, yes you are right to state that VBA is VBA, but ...

Comment: @ZevSpitz ... but many of the "run of the mill" [<app>-vba] question come from a business application of programming into a specific set of problems, unlike [excel] and [vba] tag where thing like 3rd party <app> manipulation, db integration and higher paradigm programming issues are tackled, essentially, you (meta) might not notice this but a big service the tag does is to expedite both business background question and programming question enabling users to monitor three sides of the spectrum without missing intricate questions in a sea of low quality question.

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu tl;dr: maximize the answerer happiness.

Comment: @Braiam I don't think the consequences are that severe; I would suggest that only users who are unfamiliar with the term "VBA" will be affected. Such users would start off by tagging with [tag:excel], and possibly [tag:macros] (because "Macro Recorder"). What do questions asked by these users gain by the additional [tag:excel-vba]? And if the intent is to allow even these users to differentiate between _an Excel problem that can be solved with a program_ vs _an Excel problem that can be solved with a worksheet function_, users can be directed to the tag pair instead of [tag:excel-vba].

Comment: @Braiam Or do you mean the tag community vs the community on meta? Do you have any reason to assume the meta community's stance doesn't represent the tag community's?

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu _the highest voted answer clearly states_ I understood the first comment exchange as implying that the author is willing to split the tags, as long as once the user has tagged with [tag:vba] there would also be a prompt for application-specific tags. But you are correct, that the answer seems to be against the split.

Comment: @ZevSpitz you sure that a 20% slower answer rate isn't a bad result?

Comment: @Braiam All your data shows is that a tag pair gets answers more quickly then each individual tag. I suspect that if you were to limit the questions to those tagged with both [tag:excel] + [tag:vba], the percentages would be similar to those of the single [tag:excel-vba]; as opposed to questions tagged only [tag:excel] or only [tag:vba]. The same would be true of any tag pair -- a question tagged [tag:c#] and [tag:wpf] would in general get quicker answers then a question tagged only [tag:c#] or a question tagged only [tag:wpf]. (We've had this discussion before, but ATM I can't access SEDE.)

Comment: @ZevSpitz - You're really starting to grasp at straws now to support your position in this fool's errand. Statistics clearly show that having the xxxxx-vba tags are beneficial to both the questioner and the answerer. You seem to be now claiming that such benefits are irrelevant compared to the fact that 3-5 tags can be removed from service. What a crock!

Comment: @ZevSpitz no, that's not how central tendency statistics work. If both excel and vba tags are worse than the excel-vba, then the combination will also be worse. The average between two numbers is always between those two numbers, even if the numbers themselves are average. Also, it was a deliberate choice in the analisys taking into account how the underlying system works.

Comment: I thank you for your candor and your dedication to SO users, advanced and beginner. _You're really starting to grasp at straws now to support your position in this fool's errand._ My position hasn't changed -- 1) Excel and VBA are orhogonal concerns, so from a purely technical standpoint the tags should have been split; 2) A single tag may be slightly more discoverable to new users, and/or 3) easier to follow for answerers, but 4) it comes at the cost of multiple tagging strategies. 5) We can easily direct users to the pair of tags instead of the single combo tag, and 6) those users who ...

Comment: ... ignore direction and are unfamiliar with the term VBA will tag with [tag:excel] and possibly [tag:macros]. _Statistics clearly show that having the xxxxx-vba tags are beneficial_ Are you referring to the statistics [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370283)? I've expressed my reservations [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace/370159?noredirect=1#comment605234_370283).

Answer (score 12):

I am totally in favour of the proposed solution because it fixes the basic problem, in my opinion: currently, there are two ways one can flag a question about VBA in Excel, or any other host. As a consequence, both will be used and you always have to search for both possibilities to find all questions. There can be as much user education as you want to promote that all VBA questions in Excel should go to the combined tag; it will not work. Quite a lot of the questions in the VBA tags come from users that do not even bother to read the *How to ask* page. Why would they bother to follow any preferred convention for tagging?

This leaves two possibilities: killing all combined tags and following the convention from other languages as Java to require tagging with the language and the framework/object model (provided the framework is important) or removing the standalone tag for the language.

As already argued in other answers, removing the standalone tag is a problem for several reasons. To name a few:

1. VBA is a full blown programming language of its own with its standard library (mostly concerned with string manipulation functions, but not only) that is identical among all hosts. Thus, there are questions that only concern the language and not any specific object model, like [Check if a string contains another string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15585058/5536802).
   There are actually frequently questions in combined tags that actually concern the syntax or problems solved within the standard library, e.g. [vba - rediming 2d array and trying to find the length of the 2nd of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51045128/vba-rediming-2d-array-and-trying-to-find-the-length-of-the-2nd-of-the-array) from about 7 hours ago.
2. There are hundreds of hosts for which there is no combined tag and generating them would create a lot of basically unused tags.
3. The previous point cannot be circumvented by leaving the standalone tag only for those and relying on user education to promote the convention because most people do not read.
4. You cannot safely tag only with the host application: at least in the case of Excel, you can program in the host application alone without ever touching VBA.

Comment: I think this hits on the biggest issue.  If the goal is to have only 1 way to tag, the hyphenated tag has to be the one to go.  Neither of the individual tags can be removed, because they are both on-topic by themselves.  If you keep the hyphenated tag, there will *always* be multiple ways to tag the question.

Comment: RE 4: This raises another point -- just as you can program in the host without VBA, you can program in VBA without touching the host. If I have a question about manipulating the Word object model from within Excel, why should that be tagged [tag:excel]?

Answer (score 7):

Two similar questions have been asked before, in relation to Android: [kotlin-android](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361552/burninate-kotlin-android) (burnination request) and [android-java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348515/6296561) (tag request). They're not related to VBA, but they're related to this problem.

> We don't create tags for combinations of languages and frameworks. If a question uses the Java language, then java is a legitimate tag for that question. And however much you may see the Android additions as alien, the actual source code is still using the Java language. - [Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348544/6296561)

Now, I'm not a VBA developer. However, I did talk to someone who does know VBA before posting this, and from what I've been told, VBA (the ***language***, looking aside bindings to Excel, Word, and others) is the same. Considering the two previous posts on related topics, and especially the `[android-java]` request, there's no point in separating the tags. VBA is a single language, and the bindings to Excel, Word, and others end up being specific APIs, **not** separate programming languages.

And I'd like to establish the fact that VBA is a single language. See [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/getting-started-with-vba-in-office):

> You can perform these tasks and accomplish a great deal more by using VBA for Office−a simple, but powerful **programming language** that you can use to extend Office applications.

(emphasis mine)

Also (from someone who's familiar with VBA):

> It is the same language. All current hosts should use VBA7. The difference is the object model. - [Source](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45342535#45342535)

VBA is, regardless of what program it's used in, a single language. Also, Microsoft hasn't defined a a "Visual Basic for Excel" (or any other single program) language anywhere. Why should Stack Overflow?

And while we're burninating [*-vba], the other tags ([powerpoint-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-vba)[word-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-vba)[access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba)[outlook-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook-vba)[microsoft-project-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-project-vba) and [visio-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visio-vba)) should also be retagged with the appropriate tags.

Comment: Note that we do have "specific APIs" tags.

Comment: It's the same as with natural language dialects: once dialects are sufficiently apart, they are considered different languages, and it's up for judgement where to draw the line. I sounded one such judgement from SO needs' standpoint in my answer.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev _It's the same as with natural language dialects_ To continue your analogy, two speakers of the King's English, one quoting a statement in French and one in Russian, are both using the same language and dialect, even as they are each quoting a separate external "language".

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev  _it's up for judgement where to draw the line_ I think the line is quite clear. Anything which is available in **every** implementation of the langauge, in **every** possible runtime environment, in **every** possible runtime configuration, can be considered part of the language. For example, whereever I write Python I will have access to the standard library, so the standard library is an inevitable part of discussions on the Python language. Other examples include the Javascript `Date` and `Regex` types; and the VBA `Collection` type. But if there are "things" which exist ...

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev ... in only specific implementations / environments / runtime configurations, those cannot be considered part of the core language. For example, the .NET Framework can be accessed from IronPython, and Java classes can be accessed from Jython, but neither are available from CPython. It is possible to have a Javascript environment without jQuery (GASP!) even within the browser, so jQuery is not a part of Javascript, but simply a referenced Javascript library. By extension, the Excel object model types are not a part of VBA, because it is possible to have VBA code without these ...

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev ... types available (in a different host application); rather the Excel object model types are simply a referenced library in a particular VBA environment (albeit one that when the host application is Excel, is made available by default (like VS project templates) and cannot be removed). OTOH, the Excel object model types can be trivially added to any VBA environment, and can be also used entirely independently of VBA; this is at odds with your assertion that the Excel object model types somehow create a new dialect of VBA.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a full-time VBA-For-Excel Developer, and I run my entire business around it.

Generally speaking, I understand and agree with the fact that the language and the application should be separate tabs - after all, VBA is VBA regardless of where it's written, or what program it's attached to, regardless if it's Excel, Word, or a straight VBS script. Java, like another poster mentioned, doesn't get application-language pair tags, it gets tagged on the language, and a second tag for the application.

With that being said, I think the Excel-VBA (And to a smaller extent, Word and Access-VBA) tags are a bit special in some respects. While it makes perfect sense for most programmers and technically-minded people what's going on with getting the right language and the right application, a large number (perhaps even the vast majority) of people dabbling in Excel-VBA are novices in programming, looks to write some of their first scripts. Not their first useful script, not their first real-world script, their first script.

I remember when I was starting out, having a strong background in math, a hatred for repetitive tasks, and an idea that this "VBA" thing would help me out. I used stack overflow extensively, and Excel-VBA is the only tag I followed. I'd click on that tag when I had some spare time, and read various questions and answers to improve my understanding. I wouldn't say it wouldn't have been doable without the tag, but it helped immensely. It helped me stumble upon posts such as [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and [How to use Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops). Those two posts I link fairly often - they're just that good.

I'll often go looking for questions with the Excel-VBA tag to answer - they're fun. Straight VBA is often not something I'm able to deal with, and the Excel tag is usually code for "This should be on Superuser but I found Stack Overflow first", and don't seem to be particularly high-quality questions.

Additional good points I'd like to quickly echo, in no particular order:

If Excel-VBA-Mac is going away, there should at least be something like a [VBA-Mac] tag - VBA for macs is so different as to nearly be an entirely new language.

Syntax: There's quite a bit of difference, at the base, of Excel-VBA VS Word-VBA VS Access-VBA. While you can get all of the references loaded in to make one act like the rest, this is not very intuitive, and nearly every answer assumes that the references for the application in question are loaded in.

Is there another language out there where different aspects have wildly different base references loaded in, and people answering the questions just know what references are in by default, and which ones need to be mentioned as needing to add for the solution given?

In conclusion: I'm heavily biased, but I think Excel-VBA, Word-VBA, and Access-VBA should be spared as a special case.

Comment: The "How to avoid Select" link is useful for peoplw writing programs against the Excel object model in any COM language -- C# and any .NET language, Javascript (under WSH or ASP classic), Python + win32com, Delphi -- not just VBA. It's also useful from any host -- Access, Word, Powerpoint -- not just Excel. I think keeping [tag:excel-vba] would be a loss for those people.

Comment: _Is there another language ... _ I think the confusion stems from a combination of 2 factors: 1) the only way to write, compile and run hosted VBA is through the VBA editor, and 2) the only way to get to the editor is through the host application. You're starting with the application/document and adding some macros to it. In virtually every other programming environment (from my admittedly limited experience) you have to make some kind of concious decision as to API and language outside of the actual runtime environment: WPF or ASP.NET? React or Angular JS? C++ or Rust?

Answer (score 5):

Most tags are associated with a specific domain: *if the question has x / deals with x / is in the domain of x, tag with [x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x)*.

What aspect of a question should trigger the use of [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)?

1. **The question is about Excel and VBA**? So tag with [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), and that's it.
2. **The question targets the Excel object model**? The `-vba` part of the tag implies something VBA-specific; it seems odd to tag a question targeting the Excel object model in C# with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba).
3. **The code in the question is run under the Excel host / embedded in an Excel workbook**? This doesn't usually matter. As long as the task at hand (e.g. create a Word document) and the target object model (using the `Documents` collection and the `Add` method) is the same, the answers will be the same, irrespective of hosting application, or location of the code.
4. **The code involves unique syntax available only in VBA hosted under Excel** such as cell references with brackets (`[A1].Value = "Foo"`), or brackets as evaluation commands (`result = [VLOOKUP(A1,A1,1,0)]`)? These obscure edge case are very rarely used, and could adequately be covered by [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel)+[vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba).

I could get behind 2. [if the tag was called something language-agnostic, such as [excel-object-model]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300056/synonymize-rename-excel-vba-and-others-to-excel-automation-excel-active); such a tag would be useful from other languages / environments as well. (In fact, there already is an [excel-automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-automation) tag which could serve as a synonym target for [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba).

Otherwise, I support this proposal.

---

Something else to consider: beginners to VBA + Excel [may not know that they are using VBA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace/370159?noredirect=1#comment603782_370135) -- they may know nothing more than the terms *Excel* and *macro*. Today, these beginners are helped by having the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag pop up for them in the tag list. Nevertheless, I think it more appropriate to solve this with an additional prompt: when the user enters only<sup>1</sup> the [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) tag (or tags of other applications commonly associated with VBA), the prompt should ask to add the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag as well.

<sup>1. If the user has entered a different language tag -- e.g. [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) -- it doesn't make sense to ask the user if he wants to add [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) as well. Also, if there are any other tags, the user is presumably familiar with the tag system and doesn't need this prompt.</sup>

---

Much has been made of the supposed uniqueness of VBA hosted under Excel, as if it was a new programming language with the name Excel-VBA. I can conceive of two reasons why programming with VBA hosted under Excel might be mistaken for a new language:

1. the types in the Excel type library (e.g. `Worksheet` object, and `Sheets` collection) are available (by default, and cannot be removed)
2. the global variables provided by the Excel host (e.g. `Application` global property, `ActiveSheet` global property

As a thought experiment, let's say VBA is opened via Word (which by the above logic should be called the Word-VBA language), a reference to the Excel object model is added, and a module with some public variables/functions (`e.g. Public Application As New Excel.Application`) is created. Now both the Excel types and the Excel global objects are available -- is this now a new language called Word-Excel-VBA? Or Excel-Word-VBA? And if the Access type library is added, should we say that we now have 27 different languages?

Isn't it more sensible to say that VBA is one domain<sup>2</sup>, Excel is another domain, Word is a third domain and Access is a fourth; and there can be overlap between these domains?

<sup>2. The word **domain** here instead of "language" is intentional, because the SO tagging system doesn't differentiate between "language" tags and "API" tags; tags are mapped to appropriate domains.</sup>

---

As to the conception that VBA is in itself too narrow a concern without relevant object models:

- There are many similar language/environments pairings:

  - What would C# be without .NET Framework? And yet, C# and the .NET Framework are two orthogonal concerns -- C# can be used against .NET Core or .NET Standard, and .NET Framework can be used equally well from other languages.
  - Javascript can only be run within a host (the browser, Node.js, or WSH), yet no one would argue that there is no place for a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.
- The common VBA shared across environments is rather minimal -- language syntax, `Collection` type, 8 modules with some functions. However, there are many problems for which there is a unique answer for VBA, and is appropriate to all VBA environments:

  - regular expressions (VBScript Regular Expression library)
  - database-style connectivity to databases, spreadsheets and text files (ADODB, or DAO/ACE)
  - file system parsing operations and file I/O (Scripting.FileSystemObject)
  - HTML parsing (MSHTML), web scraping and browser automation
  - XML parsing (MSXML)
  - spell checking (Word object model spell checker)
  - image processing (WIA)
  - and more...

  These answers to the specified problems are equally applicable in Word-hosted VBA, Excel-hosted VBA or Access-hosted VBA.

The data from [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/869358/counts-of-related-vba-associated-applications-for-questions-tagged-vba-or-vba):

```
AppCount  PostCount
--------- ----------
0         313751
1         114953
2           4816
3             46
```

shows that almost 3 times as many questions tagged VBA have no association with an application. vs questions that have an association with a single application. In addition, a sizable number of posts are indeed associated with multiple applications. This would suggest that VBA must be treated as a domain independent from any single application.

Comment: There is a question of practicality versus purity. The people who ask questions are not always going to know the right-from-an-academic-perspective tags to use. The people who are likely to answer are (we hope!) more knowledgeable than the askers. So it's more practical to meet the askers where they are, or at least *toward* where they are. The tagging conventions should ideally serve both the askers and the answerers. And this will not be consistent across all topics. A "beginner Haskell" question isn't going to be asked by the same kind of beginner as a beginner Excel-VBA question.

Comment: @JohnY Except that the beginner in VBA+Excel [may not even know that it's called VBA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace/370159?noredirect=1#comment603782_370135), and it's impractical to define a tagging strategy for these beginners. There would have to be some kind of prompt when the user selects the [tag:excel] tag, to select other appropriate tags; and that prompt might as well ask about the [tag:vba] tag, instead of being used to perpetuate the combination tag.

Comment: Probably very uncommon, but a decade ago I did something at my job that could've been appropriately tagged with [c#] and [excel-vba].  As a proof of concept I wrote a script in the latter that offloaded a calculation to the former.  Speedup went from ~1day to <1 minute; with most of the time being spent in the VBA scraping the spreadsheet to generate an array of data to pass to the C# code via COM.

Comment: @DanNeely Although perhaps even your scenario could have been tagged [tag:excel]+[tag:vba]+[tag:c#].

Comment: @ZevSpitz It predated my time here, but the key tag would've been [COM], and as much on Supeuser as here.  The baseline C# implementation already existed, scraping a sheet into a 2d array is vba101 level stuff.  COM's learning curve is a sheer cliff face with landmines and concertina wire at the base.  Figuring out what security lockdowns needed relaxed to get it running on the secure production network after I got it working on my dev laptop was just as painful as figuring out the initial interop.

Comment: Excel VBA is drastically different from some other forms of VBA, ergo it should have its own tag.  If an arbitrary number of tags were allowed on posts, it would make sense to delete, maybe.

Comment: Actually, the VBA in Excel depends on the actual version of Excel you're using.  It's a little better with the newer versions, but the syntax and libraries are exceedingly difficult to deal with in older versions of office, which are still out there in the wild.

Comment: @DylanBrams So there should be an [tag:excel-2007-vba] tag, [tag:excel-2010-vba] tag, an [tag:excel-2013-vba] tag, an [tag:excel-2016-vba] tag?

Comment: Actually, in my opinion, yes, but that's an entirely different story.  A vba tag, an vba-office tag, a vba-excel tag, and on down.  An organized tag cloud with many to many parents and children where excel-2013-vba has logical parents.  But then, that's just the way I'd design it.  :)

Comment: @DylanBrams I've expanded my answer to include my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

If others use the site (and this tag) how I do, then there might be fewer answerers for Excel VBA questions if this happened. If I'm an outlier then I'll go back to lurking on the `matlab` tag and you can pass me by!

- For reasons noted by others (application specificities) I'm less interested in the broader `vba` tag,
- I'm not interested in non-VBA questions within the `excel` tag.

So...

- Having the `excel-vba` tag favourited means it's one click to view the questions within the intersection of Excel and VBA.
- If this change happened, I guess I'd have to search `[excel][vba]`, which frankly I'm too lazy to do when taking a quick click away from the day job...

There's often many low quality questions to wade through in the Excel pool anyway, so making it harder to find on topic questions within them is just discouraging as an answerer.

Comment: IMO if you can answer a VBA question, then it doesn't matter what the host application is. If you're writing "PowerPoint-VBA" and tag it as such when you have a question about how VBA *the language* works, i.e. you're having a problem with some part of the loop syntax or arrays or whatever, then your question will be getting fewer eyeballs just because it's not tagged with "Excel-VBA", yet 100% of the "Excel-VBA" crowd would be qualified to answer that "PowerPoint-VBA" question. The host/libs only matter if the question is about *that*.

Comment: @Mat There is a difference between whether I'm *qualified* to answer a question, and whether I'm *looking* to answer a question. I've never used VBA within PowerPoint for instance, so don't know how the object hierarchy works for slides and stuff on them and I'm not familiar with the use cases. I do know Excel's object model well and can easily advise on tasks about summarising data or doing computations. My point was that if they're all in one bin, I wouldn't look to answer the additional stuff which was previously hidden by using the `excel-vba` "filter". The `vba` tag is for generalists.

Comment: But what the OP is suggesting, is that PowerPoint questions would be tagged with [tag:vba]+[tag:powerpoint], so all you can do to avoid PowerPoint questions, is avoid the [tag:powerpoint] tag when you see it... though, I can assure you that being unfamiliar with an OM isn't a showstopper at all. For example `Slides` is clearly an object collection class, just like the `Worksheets` collection is - and the answer to "why am I getting 'error 9 index out of bounds'?" is exactly the same in both cases. IMO if you do VBA you should at least *see* the VBA questions and then see if you'll answer them.

Comment: @Mat thanks I was just giving an example really, my main emphasis was more on not being interested in PowerPoint centric questions by nature, not that I couldn't probably answer Qs if I wanted to. I don't think I can really summarise my thoughts any better than the last sentence in my answer... I was trying to articulate why keeping things separate is useful to me as a user. As I acknowledged in my second sentence, I may well be an outlier in how I use the site, I suspected not.

Comment: I hear ya ;-)   I *think* you could still have [tag:vba] in your "favorite tags" while having [tag:powerpoint] in your "ignored tags".

Comment: Even more than what @MathieuGuindon says, a question about manipulating an Excel workbook from VBA hosted within a Powerpoint presentation would currently be tagged [tag:powerpoint-vba], and probably not [tag:excel-vba]; you would miss that question, even if it only involved the Excel object model, and you would be qualified and interested in answering the question.

Comment: @zev I feel like we shouldn't turn this comment thread into a  discussion about what I am or am not interested in or qualified in... it's not really my point anyway, as already stated

Comment: Same argument stays for `c#`. I don't care about `unity3d`. Should we have `unity-c#`? I don't think so.

Comment: Is it really more effort to search `[excel][vba]` vs `[excel-vba]`?  If you do this so frequently that it makes a difference, just set up a favourite somewhere pointing to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel+vba

Comment: @John That's a firm yes, because I don't *search* `[excel-vba]`, I click the favourited tag from the homepage. The question *"is it more effort"* is maybe not what you meant, maybe you're asking *"could you be any more lazy complaining about 12 keystrokes?!"* which is more subjective, and as I have said multiple times it's purely down to how I interact with the site, if you're different that's fine.

Comment: @Wolfie that's covered by using a favourite link (i.e. then you don't even need to be on the site; you could just have a html file on your desktop with a bunch of links in it / whatever works best for you).  You could also set up a filter (https://stackexchange.com/filters/) and use that if you want the experience within SO.  That said; yes, typing 12 keystrokes is  more my point; you typed many more to submit this answer.

Comment: @JohnLBevan then it involves more effort duplicating a functionality that the site already have.

Comment: To my mind the issue of being able to search on combinations of tags is different to the issue on replacing a single tag.  Perhaps for the `[excel-vba]` question we should accept that it's split, but also upvote the option to have [favourite tag combos](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345405/support-favourite-tag-combinations) to avoid this split from creating a problem for those with this concern / to provide the same benefits to others wanting to search for specific combinations?

Comment: SE gave us lemons @John, we have to make do with those we already have because they usually take too much time to give apples. The new-new-nav was supposed to fix these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a very bad idea to burninate the "xxx-vba" combo tags. It's important to keep the issues of "features" separate from issues of "development". The hypenated xxx-vba tags represent the exclusive application development subsystems present in vba-enabled software suites. These are programming issues, not features. Yes, the the two are related, but in a hierarchical relationship; the programming issues affect features, but features do not necessarily affect programming. I feel the burnination of the xxx-vba tags would open floodgates of unnecessary commenting and useless or even entirely incorrect answers on vba-related issues by posters with little or no knowledge of vba. It seems to me it would just get very messy, very quickly.

Comment: I don't agree with this prophecy, as other languages do just fine without separating between "features" and "development"

Comment: There is also the issue that VBA comes in many different flavors: Excel, Access, Word, Autocad, CorelDraw, SpiceWorks, Burk Technology Autopilot, and tons more that I could never name. Each of them has a different set of unique objects, and their respective communities surely have customary ways of doing things. Lumping them all together into "VBA" will be a train wreck.

Comment: This concern is entirely addressed by requiring an application tag to go along with the [tag:vba] tag as Shog's question above explains.

Comment: @spinjector _There is also the issue that VBA comes in many different flavors._ By analogy, Javascript also comes in many different "flavors" -- the objects available to Javascript running under Node.js are different from Javascript running in the browser; there are also different objects available between browsers.

Comment: _The hypenated xxx-vba tags represent the exclusive application development subsystems present in vba-enabled software suites._ In virtually all cases, these questions are about using the application object model (AKA the application development subsystem) from VBA. There is nothing inherently VBA about this usage; it is available to any Automation-supporting language.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. I've programmed many flavors of VBA, even non-Microsoft ones in 3rd-party software. Here is my major concern: I only want to watch for Excel-VBA posts. How do I do that? Does the SO Watch system allow boolean combinations..? Aka [Excel] AND [VBA]..? Because if I set up watches for [Excel] and [VBA], I'm going to be inundated with posts about sheet formatting and/or VBA commands in Word and products I have nothing to do with, and I want none of those. So how do I filter to only "[Excel] AND [VBA]"..? That's my concern.

Comment: _So how do I filter to only "[Excel] AND [VBA]"..? That's my concern._ That concern has already been raised in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370328/111794). But your wording of _flavors of VBA_ is inaccurate -- there are no multiple flavors of VBA; the keywords, operators, syntax, built-in data types, and basic VBA DLL library are all the same; the only distinction between environments is which libraries have been referenced. And even that is not set in stone -- depending on the task at hand, you can add a reference to the appropriate library and use its types. ...

Comment: ... For example, if you want to manipulate an instance of the Excel application, you can do so from Access, from Word, or from Excel itself.

Answer (score 1):

> IMHO, there's **no value** to having a hyphenated tag here

Now let’s answer that with something no one was asking for: data!

Let’s look at some metrics of how would this impact some metrics that some would consider important, [like average time to answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/868307/time-to-answer):

```
TagName       AvgHoursToAnswer StdevHoursToAnswer
------------- ---------------- ------------------
excel         11.2375079384795 51.9906868085633
excel-formula 8.53223698852936 45.8399886104636
excel-vba     8.85261099513078 44.6285979712553
vba           10.3014423699923 47.6375644035023
```

There's something interesting here. Notice how excel-formula and excel-vba has 20% better metric, also their standard deviation is lower, for at least 2013 to 30 days ago and ignoring answers older than 30 days. Now let’s look at more recent time-frame, like only 2017:

```
TagName       AvgHoursToAnswer StdevHoursToAnswer
------------- ---------------- ------------------
excel         10.5826682817362 48.9460805821794
excel-formula 7.11677955025602 37.4468054854611
excel-vba     8.42461959468619 42.7178860885887
vba           9.29170590635159 42.8963554812758
```

Still, we see that for questions asked on 2017 all of them have better metrics. Now, both queries but only for nice answers (score >= 10):

```
TagName       AvgHoursToAnswer StdevHoursToAnswer
------------- ---------------- ------------------
excel         17.7576634659351 67.7486056824381
excel-formula 1.50340277777778 4.17555973455374
excel-vba     10.1264616402116 49.9699284813992
vba           11.2438425925926 47.8981707740914
```

```
TagName   AvgHoursToAnswer StdevHoursToAnswer
--------- ---------------- ------------------
excel     32.057922705314  50.2784925969659
excel-vba 20.4515625       44.1700614816757
vba       18.981081871345  40.9082771129543
```

The reason why Excel formula questions is so low is because there are only two answers with score >= 10 in the tag since October 2013.

Let’s see the average answer score:

```
TagName       avgscore          stdscore
------------- ----------------- ----------------
excel         0.750747550108062 1.12763906502791
excel-formula 0.846072857443672 1.12493370194906
excel-vba     0.814591761677087 1.20213992022188
vba           0.801218007403574 1.19886504472732
```

Questions using Excel have lower answer score on average, but that's maybe because not many people answer them:

```
TagName       qcount acount aperq
------------- ------ ------ --------
excel         30061  36983  1.230265
excel-vba     18318  23036  1.257560
vba           21688  26918  1.241147
```

The proposal seems to cause these metrics to be worse. Tag [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) seems to be more efficient as a signal that answerers with knowledge in Excel VBA that their expertise could be useful. This is shown by faster and better scored answers and marginally better answering rate, and that's valuable.

Comment: Note that in these queries I didn't excluded questions that had more than 1 tag, so the differences could be even more extreme.

Comment: 1) Wouldn't it be more appropriate to compare metrics for questions tagged [tag:excel-vba] vs questions tagged with _both_ [tag:excel] and [tag:vba] (as opposed to the metrics of questions tagged with each individually)? the combo tag would be replaced with _both_ tags. 2) Also, it might be that the reason for the lower metrics on the individual tags is because of the existence of the common tag; perhaps a better comparison would be the metrics of [tag:excel-vba] vs the metrics of [tag:vba]+[tag:regex] or [tag:vba]+[tag:mshtml] or tag:vba]+[tag:adodb], which have never had a combo tag.

Comment: @ZevSpitz no, because the system doesn't treat each tag combination differently. I'm measuring the capacity of each *individual* tag of achieving an specific result: producing answers. If a question had different tags, the probabilities would be the union of all the specific tags probabilities. So if you used all three tags, you could bring about any of all three results. That's why my comment points out that the results could be even more extreme. Also, remember that I'm using the current state of the tags, not the state when they were answered.

Comment: @ZevSpitz That would explain excel vs excel-vba, but not excel-vba vs vba. I included the count of questions that have any of the tag for that same reason. If you want, you could include all those tags in this query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/868304/time-to-answer and check out the results. Again, because the system behave the same whenever you use 1 vs set of tags, it doesn't make sense to evaluate combinations of tags.

Comment: This assumes that it's the tag that draws answers, not the answerability/quality of the question...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon it doesn't matter that the question is perfect, if there's no discoverability it would be a unanswered question anyways. Have you known any prolific answerer that doesn't use tags one way or another to consume questions?

Comment: Point is, we can't know that from the data ATM, because we don't know how many Qs are asked vs answered, how many Qs were tagged by the OP vs retagged by a regular, ...are you even following these tags we're talking about? Do you know how many of these questions are utter "gimmeh teh codez" crap? I do. Some days, it's every single question asked in the past hour that's unanswerable, downvoted and collecting close votes. Shame SEDE doesn't include the deleted questions.

Comment: You can't know anything perfectly accurate @mathieu, that doesn't mean you don't try. Even considering retaggings, if you follow previous discussions you will notice that at most there were only 500 known instances of mass retags, and they were both ways. That along with the situation where people [gets jobs alert for tech they haven't worked before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/523153), you could say that people err on the side of adding **more** tags or keeping them on the more side, rather than less or removing them, which again points to the situation of my first comment.

Comment: There can be many reasons for the difference between these tags. For example, questions in [tag:vba] might be about more obscure object models (such as [tag:visio]), which likely get slower answers. While I'm 100% for making decisions based on actual data, I don't think you can deduce anything relevant to this question from these statistics.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I believe those deleted questions are present in the SEDE PostsWithDeleted table, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth might be that changed recently. Last I checked, SEDE didn't include any roomba'd posts, i.e. you could only get very-recently-deleted posts,

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'm not aware of any change, but I've taken a random roomba'd question that came up in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90230/socvr-request-graveyard) over a year ago, and I can [find it](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/868654) on SEDE. So I think you can reliably write queries to analyze roomba'd bad questions.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth well, you could just remove those ~200 questions. Still, comparing it to the 21k questions, is a drop in the bucket. Remember, my query ignore answers older than 30 days, so late answers aren't even considered.

Comment: @pnuts what? What has to do less than 500 questions compared with the 18 to 30 thousands which going by their deviations doesn't seems to be the same population?  How would that afect significativelly the analisys which deliberatelly ignores answers posted 30 days older than the question? Remember, my analisys is a within a subset of questions, which may or may not be affected by the retagging, which were done towards both ways, that inflated [excel], [excel-vba] and [vba]

Comment: Note that because of the structure of the joins in your query, questions with multiple tags will have more weight in the average time-to-answer than questions with a single tag. Removing that inaccuracy, and comparing the single tags against pairs of tags, shows that questions tagged [tag:excel-vba] actually have a longer average time-to-first-answer than questions tagged both [tag:excel] and [tag:vba]. ([SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/869314/discoverability-metrics-per-tag-average-time-to-first-answer?MinScore=10&MaxDaysToFirstAnswer=30))

Comment: @ZevSpitz "Note that in these queries I didn't excluded questions that had more than 1 tag" you are not saying anything new. This is a deliberate choice due how the underlying system works.

Comment: @pnuts "Some Qs have these tags added/subtracted many times over" that's the point. And even then, if there was so much shuffle, one would expect standard deviations not to be so different between each other. That's why my analysis holds, the subsets of the populations (questions with any of the tags) are too different.

Comment: Whoa! *50.2784925969659* - that is 15 significant digits. I don't think that is warranted. How many data points are required for 15 significant digits for an estimate of a standard deviation?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I was being lazy and just copied the results.

Comment: _This is a deliberate choice due how the underlying system works._ [My query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/869314/discoverability-metrics-per-tag-average-time-to-first-answer) seems to indicate quite strongly that when the set of questions is limited to those tagged with the pair of tags, the average time-to-first-answer goes down. OTOH, I would have thought tagging with [tag:excel-vba] would have a similar effect as the individual tags, but I am surprised to see that [tag:excel]+[tag:vba] has a significantly lower average time-to-first-answer than [tag:excel-vba].

Answer (score 0):

## Please, please burninate the `Excel-VBA` tag!

**Why remove the "nice compact, single tag" in favour of using 2 separate tags?**

- It mathematics it's called ***"lowest common denominator"***.
- With databases it's called ***"normalization"***.

> *The most flexibility comes from breaking data storage down to its fundamental parts.*

---

## Do you care about new users?

When a new users is tagging their VBA/Excel question (or looking for answers), they are most likely to pick **excel** and **vba**.

The same applies when someone new to the site is looking for an answer by tag.

---

For the reasons above, and others, I believe all compound tags should be removed, but let's start with this one.

---

**Incidentally, here's a recent question count, by combination of tags:**

```
  Excel or VBA tags used (others may also be present)
 ---------------------------------------- -------- -----
  [vba]+[excel]+[excel-vba]                 40541   19%
  [vba]+[excel]                             19325    9%
  [vba]+[excel-vba]                         12255    6%
  [excel]+[excel-vba]                       12293    6%
  [excel-vba]                               13649    6%
  [vba]                                     28768   13%
  [excel]                                   75521   34%

  Questions with any Excel or VBA Tag      218907
```

Comment: Really absolute beginners are liable not to know that they are using VBA, and are liable to pick only [tag:excel]. But I think the only solution for these beginners is a prompt for [tag:vba] when the user chooses [tag:excel]; and relying on subsequent reviewing/retagging if the user ignores said prompt.

Comment: They are more likely tot pick the `[macros]` tag, due to the name of the macro recorder. However that tag has no connection to VBA. A prompt would be helpfull here.

Comment: *[new users] are most likely to pick excel and vba.* - based on...?

Comment: Just to go a little further with your stats, is there a scenario where users have a non vba related question regarding Excel and still makes the question fit for SO, knowing that SO is a coding forum? If so, what about them if excel-vba tag is burninated? I like your stats, but this is still a missing info for me, especially when we see that the excel only tag is the most used with 34%.

Comment: @Wolfie - based on unofficial survey of small random sample of new SO users, and SO veterans.  Basically, "if you had a question like this, which tags would you pick?"  I can probably query SEDE to find exact stats on original (pre-edit/PostHistory) questions from new users if that information is deemed significant enough to help sway this decision.

Comment: @V.Brunelle - I think your issue is related to the tour/FAQ's more than the tags. I think most users that post non-programming questions on SO aren't doing so intentionally. (Remember, Microsoft.com encourages new users to come here for any kind of support). Also I don't see how that would be affected with or without [tag:excel-vba].

Comment: @V.Brunelle I can think of three such areas: 1) Automating the Excel application and related objects from a programming language other than VBA; 2) Accessing / manipulating data from an Excel workbook directly (ADODB or OpenXML); 3) Worksheet functions, which if sufficiently complex, are considered a type of programming here. If [tag:excel-vba] would be burninated, then all these would use [tag:excel] and further tags as needed ([tag:c#], [tag:python], [tag:adodb], [tag:openxml], [tag:worksheet-functions]).

Comment: @pnuts I mean the specific tag [tag:worksheet-function]; it was a misspelling.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the answers there are a lot of very good points around VBA in Windows vs. Mac, the host application, and tag limits.

*The crux of the matter, from my inspection, revolves around user knowledge - does the average user know the difference, and know how to tag their questions?*

To that end, the type of solution I would present would provide more granularity to the user's intent and help them conform to a standard. I would do this by breaking apart the tagging structure in the following way:

- **Programming Language Tags:** [VBA]
- **(Optional) Host Application/IDE:** [Excel 16], [Word 16], [PowerPoint 16], [MS Access 16], [CAD], etc.
- **Operating System:** [MacOS], [Windows 10], etc.
- **Additional Tags:** [Regular Descriptor Tags]

We ask users to be more specific in asking their questions, why not help guide them with the way we tag?

This would work for other languages too:

- **Programming Language Tags:** [Python 3.6]
- **(Optional) Host Application/IDE:** [Jupyter]
- **Operating System:** [Windows 10]
- **Additional Tags:** [Seaborn], [Data-Viz]

Comment: The purpose of tags is to broadly categorize questions, not provide all possible details in the tag. For example, most questions regarding the Excel object model will have the same answer in the context of the object model for Excel 2007-2016. Similarly, until we know that the question is affected by the difference between Python 3.5 and 3.6, it is better to tag with the broader [tag:python]. The issue at hand is some people seem to think that there needs to be a [tag:jupyter-python] because there is a new distinct and unique version of Python when Jupyter is running; ; ...

Comment: ... or that newcomers to Jupyter won't know to tag with [tag:python] and [tag:jupyter], or that it is easier to follow the separate [tag:jupyter] and [tag:python[ tags, over following a single combination tag.

Comment: Yeah, I think how S/O uses the data is different than building a construct that nudges users to thoroughly, properly tag

Comment: There is good reason for that. Tagging a question relating to the `os` module, with [tag:python-3.6] will not help the next person with the exact same question but running [tag:python-3.5]. Consider also, there could be tags for [timezone-gmt+5], [programmer-ethnicity-caucasian], [system-architecture-x86] -- all of these are unlikely at first glance to affect the question itself.

Answer (score -9):

The central point of the dichotomy seems to be if "Excel VBA" is a separate language or not.

It shares the syntax and basic data types with VBA of other Office products. But the similarity ends here. The object model i.e. the project organization and the entire "standard library" is completely different. And since VBA is not a general-purpose language, the app-specific machinery in VBA code absolutely dominates any similarities in syntax and any common types.

So, it seems that there's actually no such language as "VBA" -- instead, there are several tangentially similar languages: "Excel VBA", "Word VBA", "Access VBA" etc. -- in that if you have expertise in one of them, to do anything meaningful in another one, you'll have to go through a learning curve comparable to learning a new language. At least, this is what basically defines a "language" for SO purposes.

---

For SO purposes, this also means that whoever is interested in and watches questions in one of these "flavors" is not likely to be interested in all of them. And AFAICS, there's no ability to watch an intersection of tags (I'm not using the feature so I don't really know).

[Statistics seems to confirm that](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/866925/1070959/number-of-users-interested-in-different-vba-flavors): there are 2615 users with >= 5 posts in [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba), 310 in [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba) and 72 in both. For other intersections with [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba), the figures are: [word](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866925/number-of-users-interested-in-either-of-the-two-tags-and-in-both-of-them?Tag1=excel-vba&Tag2=word-vba): 66 and 20; [outlook](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866925/number-of-users-interested-in-either-of-the-two-tags-and-in-both-of-them?Tag1=excel-vba&Tag2=outlook-vba): 25 and 11; [powerpoint](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/866925/number-of-users-interested-in-either-of-the-two-tags-and-in-both-of-them?Tag1=excel-vba&Tag2=powerpoint-vba#resultSets): 34 and 14 (for the rest of the Office apps, the numbers are even smaller).

---

This means that instead, the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag shall be retired and disambiguated.

Questions that don't touch any of the app-specific features are presumed to be extremily rare, but for them, something like [vba-app-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba-app-agnostic) could be created.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174032/discussion-on-answer-by-ivan-pozdeev-merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now).

Comment: But the object model is not part of the language, is it? jQuery is not part of JavaScript either. See [Mathieu Guindon's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace/370149#370149)

Comment: You are currently measuring the number of users who have asked questions tagged with intersections of the `<app>-vba` tags. 1) This isn't equivalent to users who are interested in said intersections; the actual measurement would be to see how many users follow both tags. I wasn't able to find this information on SEDE. 2) An alternative would be to measure how many [tag:vba]-tagged questions are not tagged with [tag:excel-vba] and how many [tag:vba]-tagged questions are tagged with multiple `<app>-vba` tags. 3) I would suggest that multiple tags could indicate an question's association with ...

Comment: ... an application, e.g. [tag:excel-2007], [tag:excel-2013] both indicate the question has to do with Excel. 4) [This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/869358/counts-of-related-vba-associated-applications-for-questions-tagged-vba-or-vba) shows that there are more VBA questions unassociated with **any** application (of the `<app>-vba` applications), than questions associated with 1 application (313K vs 114K) while there is a respectable number of questions associated with two applications (4.8K).

Answer (score -22):

I think your questions aren't covering the total breadth of issues such thing would bring about:

- Is there any question that is on topic for SO which uses [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) that doesn't have anything to do with [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba)?
- If there isn't why wouldn't be [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) enough?
- If [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) isn't enough, how would someone that want to answer questions only about the Excel specific VBA, which by itself appears [to be rather extensive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/object-model-excel-vba-reference) compared to everything else?
- How about [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) questions that have nothing to do with vba (remember, [excel formulas are on topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261927/792066), so if I follow excel questions and want to answer questions about formulae I would suddenly find myself with a mixed bag of VBA questions and formula question)?
- What about other office vba objects, like access, word, outlook, etc.?
- What makes [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) special compared to other hypernated tags? Only the "endless debates"?

Comment: The statement of your 4th question answers your first.

Comment: Excel questions already are "a mixed bag of VBA and formulas", since it often boils down to "this is fairly complicated and I'm trying to get it done without VBA if possible, but if it can be shown that's impossible then bring on the VBA". If anything it'd be nice if the formula experts can weigh in on questions that start off presuming VBA is necessary... but they probably already do.

Comment: @Dave I know. With the first I'm asking the more general question: which other topic**s** that aren't related to vba are on topic, be it formulas or something else.

Comment: **1)** Yes. **2)** N/A, see 1. **3)** this is a fragment that doesn't ultimately ask anything **4)** tag them with just [tag:excel] obviously. **5)** Tag them with the application tag where appropriate. **6)** See your own words in 3. It's huge compared to the others.

Comment: @TylerH 4) Yeah, so what about those tagged also with vba? Why someone that follows only excel should see vba questions?

Comment: @TylerH 3) Its huge, but so it is access, why nobody is talking about access?

Comment: @Braiam Well going forward, they won't, necessarily; this is only for questions currently tagged [tag:excel-vba] so that tag information that may be useful is not *lost*. As for someone following Excel that doesn't want to see VBA, they can add VBA to their ignored or hidden tag list, or do a custom search for `[excel] -[vba]` or whatever tag combination they want. As for access... no that tag family is not really huge. The excel tag family (e.g questions with `[excel-vba]` and `[vba]` is more than an order of magnitude larger.

Comment: Yes, there are thousands and thousands of questions on SO that concern Excel but have no connection to VBA. You really could've just looked at the tag instead of asking that question, so since I've answered it I'm going to ask that you at least try to research your other questions.

Comment: @Shog9 but you didn't include that question nor the results of *your* research, so somebody gotta ask. I had researched it several iterations back, but came to the same conclusion: since tags are means for answerers to find questions they are able to answer, excel-vba seems to be pretty effective doing so compared to the alternatives.

Comment: I explicitly requested that folks not take this opportunity to challenge Excel's topicality. That's in the question. I linked to plenty of past discussions if you want more info, but I'm not trying to rehash all that here.