# What is the difference between [formula] and [formulas]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Besides the obvious difference: **s**?

I came across this question today: [Counting digit in column based on subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288636/counting-digit-in-column-based-on-subject)

And noticed it uses a couple of tags with (almost) equal meanings:

- `[excel-formula]`
- `[formula]`
- `[formulas]`

For now I think we shouldn't stray into `[excel-formula]` too much, as the propper debate there would be the same as for: [Merging the excel-vba into vba - speak now, or forever hold your peace](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace)

But that still leaves two tags that are a lot alike.

The tag wiki's are:

> `[formula]`: A formula is a mathematical equation or expression that performs various operations on variables to produce an outcome.
>
> `[formulas]`: A generic tag for questions concerning spreadsheet formulas. Use only when there is no more specific tag, such as [excel-formula] or [lotus-formula].

Is there really a need to keep these tags seperate, or can they be merged?

Comment: I prefer it to be removed. A formula, outside of a programing context, isn't on topic. It's only on topic when it's coupled with something else that it's of the nature unique to software engineering. How to add two numbers in python is on topic, how to add two numbers is not.

Comment: (it's already in the list to be cleaned up there, but in my experience, that's not moving very fast)