# What to do now that [formulas] is remapped to [formula]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

[formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formulas) was used on several questions about spreadsheet formulas, many of them about spreadsheet formulas in Google Sheets ([google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets)).

Today I noticed that this tag was remapped to [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formula) but this tag looks "too generic" and/or inappropriate as many questions that before included [formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formulas) are not about mathematical equations/expressions.

Considering the above I will will create a new tag for Google Sheets formulas in a similar way that there are:

- [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula)
- [lotus-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lotus-formula)

UPDATE: The resulting tag was [google-sheets-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-formula)

Should [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formula) excerpt an wiki be edited to extend its "scope" to include spreadsheet formulas?

---

From [What is the difference between [formula] and [formulas]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370890/1595451)

> The tag wiki's are:
>
> > `[formula]`: A formula is a mathematical equation or expression that performs various operations on variables to produce an outcome.
> >
> > `[formulas]`: A generic tag for questions concerning spreadsheet formulas. Use only when there is no more specific tag, such as
> >     [excel-formula] or [lotus-formula].

Notes

- On [Rev 74](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/251480/74) of [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251480/1595451) to [Clean up of run-together/hyphenated and singular/plural tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251478/1595451) the [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) was added to map [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formula) - [formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formulas) pair.

Comment: Not having spent enough time with spreadsheets to understand the minutiae of, but understanding the broad strokes of spreadsheet formulas, are there *really* such substantial differences between Google and Excel that they require their own tag?

Comment: The data types and basic syntax is the same, start with `+` or `=` followed by a literal or function name; arithmetic operators are the same but there are lot of spreadsheet functions that aren't compatible between Excel and Google Sheets and some of them doesn't work the same way. it's worthy to note that custom functions have really such substancial differences.

Comment: @Makoto That's a bit like asking if it's worth distinguishing Javascript from NodeJS. There's overlap between the two sets of functions but tons of non-overlap, too. If I'm looking for help with Google Sheets formulas, using a tag that applies to Excel formulas doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @SteveBennett:  Never conflate a language with a library built in that language.  Conversely, I seek clarity in whether or not the conflation of two similar technology stacks makes sense for the site, given that the amount of on-topicality is narrow unless you're doing actual programming with them.

Comment: @Makoto: The "doing programming" is where they overlap the least.

Comment: @SteveBennett that's not a good comparison because NodeJS is a JavaScript Engine, which is comparable to other JavaScript engines such as those found in web browsers, but not to JavaScript itself which is an implementation of ECMAScript. A proper comparison would be that of JavaScript and ActionScript or Google Apps Script, all of which are implementations of ECMAScript.

Comment: @BenVoigt I created [tag:google-sheets-formula] as there other tags that use `google-sheets-` as "prefix".

Answer (score 1):

On the above question I mentioned the creation of [google-sheets-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-formula) to follow [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) and [lotus-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lotus-formula).

I think that we should remove [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formula) from questions having one of the spreadsheet tags like [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) that aren't about mathematical formulas.

- [[excel] [formula]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel+formula)

  - Consider to remove [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formula) and to add [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula)
- [[libreoffice-calc] [formula]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libreoffice-calc+formula)

  - Consider to remove [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formula)
- [[openoffice-calc] [formula]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openoffice-calc+formula)

  - Consider to remove [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formula)
- [[google-sheets] [formula]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets+formula)

  - Consider to remove [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formula) and to add [google-sheets-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-formula)