# Let's clean up Excel related tags like [countif], [vlookup], [sumif] and [worksheet-function]

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

On https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375774/1595451 I proposed to generalize [countif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/countif) and [vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vlookup) from being exclusively for [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) to include other spreadsheet apps like [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) where the related functions work the same way. After a couple of days that post achieved +0 / -9, so from my point of view it's clear that this proposal was not well received.

Side note: I just found [sumifs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sumifs) which also is for [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel), and remembered the existence of [worksheet-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function)

Considering that [countif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/countif), [vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vlookup), [sumif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sumif) and [worksheet-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function) are exclusively for [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) questions, we should remove these tags from tags about other spreasheet applications like [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) unless the question is about that app and [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) interoperability.

I think that the following searches could help to find the Q to be cleaned.

- [[google-sheets] [countif] -[excel]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets+countif+-excel)

  - Consider to remove [countif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/countif)
- [[google-sheets] [sumif] -[excel]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets+sumif+-excel)

  - Consider to remove [sumif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sumif)
- [[google-sheets] [worksheet-function] -[excel]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets+worksheet-function+-excel)

  - Consider to remove [worksheet-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function)

Related

- [What to do now that [formulas] is remapped to [formula]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375616/1595451)
- [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375532/1595451) (currently deleted) to [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/1595451)

Comment: Surely you mis-interpreted the downvotes.  Double whammy on that previous question.  Meta users do *not* like a [discussion] that is presented as a poll with two choices.  And there is a general dislike for fine-grained ambiguous tags, even if they are highly descriptive of the question.  I never figured out that one yet, nor did the questioners. Don't do this please.

Answer (score 5):

Whether or not this is a good idea is not even a concern here.  You will never be able to enforce product exclusive tags that sound generic.

So if you clean up the "misuse" of [countif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/countif) or [sumif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sumif) on questions about [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets), someone else is going to use it again and again and again, and you will find yourself constantly cleaning it up. So the only real options are to maintain the status quo (maybe with a more generic tag wiki as [you suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375774/1595451) previously) or we burninate those tags.

Based on the arguments in the accept answer of  [Should tags be created for functions of APIs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360271/should-tags-be-created-for-functions-of-apis/360290#360290), the need for the tags you mention should be questioned.  Do we really need a tag just for the countif function or formula?  How is that going to help categorize the question or help someone find questions to answer.  Does the fact that the question is about a "countif" make that much of a difference if you already know it is about excel?

On a side note, you may be misinterpretting the downvotes on that question.  No one really offered any discussion as to why making the wikis more generic is a bad idea, so people could be downvoting for other reasons.  Until someone leaves a comment explaining their concerns, you are only guessing.  The closest is BDL's comment linking to the answer i mentioned above.

Comment: "So the only real options is to" remove these tags. Seriously, a whole tag for a function??? Tags are supposed to work as the only tag on the question. These tag fail this already very low requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately the feedback given on an answer to [Make Tag Wikis for common spreadsheet functions more generic (e.g. COUNTIF and VLOOKUP)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375774/1595451) was lost for <10k rep users after it was deleted by a diamond moderator. That feedback suggested that the votes could meant disagreement

Comment: @Braiam For those that read the tags excerpt the referred tags could be used as the only tag.

Comment: @Rubén what was the feedback?  Was it a comment?  Or was it answer?

Comment: @psubsee2003 there were several comments. Anyway, do you have a concrete suggestion regarding the next action to be taken by me like improving the already posted questions, posting another question, proceed to make edit proposals for the referred tags...?

Comment: @Rubén if it was a comment, then the moderator who deleted the comments felt that they were wrong or at least misinformation.  A lot of people on meta like to say that "downvotes only mean disagreement" and the users who say that are completely wrong.

Comment: @psubsee2003 The moderator deleted the answer, the feedback was given through comments to that answer

Comment: @Rubén as for the existing questions with the tags you mentioned - I'm not sure what "improvement" you are looking to make.  The status quo seems to be acceptable.  But frankly the tags are not needed and should be removed

Comment: @Rubén moderators just don't delete meta answers for no reason.  So either it was a self delete by the author, or there were serious issues with the answer that a mod was forced to delete it.  So as it stands, your original question really doesn't have feedback and any assumption by you that the downvotes mean that people disagree is a bad assumption

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182658/discussion-between-ruben-and-psubsee2003).