# Could we use [slicers] on Google Sheets questions?

Tags: support, tags, tag-disambiguation

Few days ago Google [announced](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/08/sheets-slicers-scorecards-themes.html) that "slicers" were added to Google Sheets. We already have [slicers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slicers) (178 questions) but it's tag excerpt says (emphasis mine)

> Slicers provide buttons that you can click to filter PivotTable data **in Excel**. In addition to quick filtering, slicers also indicate the current filtering state, which makes it easy to understand what exactly is shown in a filtered PivotTable report.

There is no wiki tag.

Could we use this tag on questions that doesn't involve Microsoft Excel?

Related Q/A

- [Slicer in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56914257/1595451)
- [Google Sheets: Enabling Slicers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57435464/1595451)

Related

- [Let's clean up Excel related tags like [countif], [vlookup], [sumif] and [worksheet-function]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375834/1595451)