# The system tag suggestion for [vba] contains an error

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, suggested-tags

When you create a question with a [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag you get a pop-up notification. I guess it has to do with [this change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370095/8597922). `Outlook` seems to have made it to the list twice, although the link point to the right place.

[image: Error in a tag]

Comment: Is that tag guidance popup something editable by normal users, or a special case that the SO devs need to fix?

Comment: Stack Overflow's first freehand parallelogram?

Comment: @DanNeely This appears to be a system prompt that we don't have access to. The [tag:vba] wiki and wiki excerpt don't contain that snippet.

Comment: @DanNeely, TylerH everyone has access to it...its on the create question page.  Type in the tag vba and set your focus back to the body to write a question.  A popup appears showing exactly this.  This isn't some form that is given to certain individuals.

Comment: @JonH TylerH and I were talking about creating/editing the text, not displaying it.  ie can we fix it ourselves, or do we need to wait for an SE dev to do so.

Comment: Ahh ok no prob 

Comment: Confirmed this occurs. The link is titled wrong, though correctly points to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow... I am so sorry; I completely overlooked that.

Fixed now:

[image: powerpoint for Microsoft Powerpoint]