# Does the VBA tag warning emphasize the host application?

Tags: discussion

Choosing the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag on a question with no other tags brings up the following warning:

[image: [vba] tag warning]

with the following wording:

> ... include a tag for the **application you're developing on** ...

Does this mean the host application?

Consider a question in any of the following areas, which correspond to specific object models or VBA functions:

- file system operations -- `FileSystemObject` or functions in the VBA FileSystem module
- database processing via code -- ADODB ([adodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adodb)) or DAO/ACE
- image processing -- WIA ([wia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wia))
- XML parsing -- MSXML ([msxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msxml))
- web scraping -- MSHTML ([mshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mshtml)) and Internet Explorer automation ([internet-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer))

In order to categorize together questions in each of these areas, a tag of the **target object model** is essential; any emphasis on the host tag is at the expense of the target object model tag.

The same applies for questions manipulating objects in an application's object model. The question is the same -- and should be tagged the same -- whether the code is actually hosted by the application or not. For example, a question regarding manipulating Outlook objects should be tagged -- at a minimum -- [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outlook), irrespective of whether the code is hosted in Excel, or Word, or even Outlook itself. (This is independent of whether a tag for the host should be included at all.)

I would suggest something along the following lines (emphasis mine):

> Please make sure to include a tag for the application **or library** you're **programming against**

followed by a list of tags: the Office application tags, and other library tags commonly used in VBA.

Comment: Is this a screenshot from the actual dialog?  Because it says "use outlook for Microsoft PowerPoint"...

Comment: @bdl it is, see [Tag suggestion for vba contains an error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371981/tag-suggestion-for-vba-contains-an-error)

Answer (score 2):

I guess "developing on" was chosen as the most trivial to interpret formulation. Identifying what you're "programming against" is not as clear-cut and might confuse a novice. While the "the application you're developing on" is completely obvious: just look at the window title!

If an OP is programming in one application but against another (e.g. through the COM interface), they most likely understand more than [your average Mort](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2006/05/11/who-are-mort-elvis-and-einstein/) and are presumed to get the message regardless.

- As such, **I'm +0,1 on "programming against"** as it's more precise but is not a clear win.

Identifying all the individual libraries involved may be a nontrivial task that is likely to confuse a novice.

Besides, the warning is for the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag. Its purpose is to tell an asker what tags to add *to the [vba] tag.* Adding tags for libraries unrelated to [vba] is the general principle of tagging, and the warning is intended as a tag-specific note, not as a general tagging guideline.

- As such, **I'm against adding "libraries"** as confusing and unrelated to the warning's purpose.

Comment: Identifying the main libraries involved in a piece of code often is very trivial, as objects in VBA should be explicitly declared using the `Dim MyVariable As Libraryname.ObjectType` syntax. And that library name often is the exact tag you should use.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth _should_ being the operative word. Also, the argument that "users who are programming against one application from within another don't need this message" might also apply to additionally referenced libraries.

Comment: The VBA editor's window title says nothing about the host application, only the name of the project, which is a little roundabout. (It's also possible to determine the host application from the first icon in the toolbar.)