# What mistake did I make with this edit?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Yesterday I tried to edit a question and my edit got rejected even though I thought it was valid. The edit in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20686439

I understand that the question is overly simple and therefore maybe shouldn't have been edited or that I might have overlooked some issues that also required my attention due to my not-so-perfect English skills, however the reason for the rejection I got is pretty vague and it doesn't help me understand what was the problem.

[image: Screenshot of the edit review at the link in the first paragraph. One reviewer approved, two others rejected with, "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."]

Note that the picture that I've decided to erase in my edit includes only the code that's already present in the question and nothing else.

I don't want to damage the site by misunderstanding the rules and I'd like to do things correctly so what did I do wrong?

Comment: It looks like your edit was not rejected out of hand, that at least one reviewer thought it had merit, but I'm not a excel-vba expert, and if question quality was of extremely low quality, then it may be deemed trying to polish a poop and rejected on this account.

Comment: @Hover We don't say poop. Turd it is at best ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: how about "feces" or residual colonic expelled material?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's what I thought at first as well but the reason for rejection doesn't seem to match that, also the question already had accepted answer from 80+k rep user, which made me not flag it.

Comment: @Hover Hmm well, _crap_ might work fine ;) I upvoted your comment.

Comment: @M.Douda You probably missed to edit in some things the OP is in charge for in 1st place.

Comment: I would guess it's because you removed `''Macro1 Macro'`. I don't know VBA so maybe it means nothing but it would cause me to reject the edit if I were reviewing it. EDIT: Nevermind, that's exactly what Erik von Asmuth already said.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I don't know if I'd have rejected that, but a couple of remarks:

You haven't indented the code, while the original code was indented, just not formatted.

You've removed code comments.

You've added the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag, while not adding the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag. Per [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370095/7296893) you should tag them both, until they're merged.

Especially that second one could be grounds for rejecting the edit, as reviewers might not be able to asses the importance of these code comments. Keep in mind that reviewers might not have VBA knowledge at all, and think you've just cut out a piece of the code.

Comment: You're right, I haven't thought about that at all, these code comments are automatically generated if the code was created by recording and they're completely meaningless, it somehow didn't come across my mind that I should write that down in my comment as well. I'll remember your other remarks as well, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @M.Douda It might also have good to capitalize the title.

Comment: Also, the image link was removed.

Comment: Those who know VBA know that the "indention" and "comments" are just auto-generated spam spewed out by excel. It holds no value to preserve it.

Comment: @Lundin Preserving the indentation is good practice though. Properly indented code is easier to understand, even though it doesn't change the function.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yeah I guess, even though indention is set by the IDE if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 13):

Those who review edits are supposed to follow the rough guideline: if the edit improves the post and does not add new problems, it should be accepted.

Comments on every detail:

- Good: adding code formatting.
- Good: Removing the picture. It adds nothing to the question since the code is present in text form like we want it.
- Indifferent: Removing the comments. Doesn't matter - those who know VBA know that this is auto-generated spam from Excel with no value. However, reviewers aren't expected to know VBA. Generally edits should not remove comments.
- Bad: removing the indention. This is minor, but generally we shouldn't tamper with coding style when editing, unless the OP is using a very strange coding style.
- Good: adding [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba). This would be an appropriate tag for the question.
- Indifferent: dealing with the [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros). Yeah it is a crap tag. But not removing it is not a reason to reject the edit.

Overall your edit leaves the post in much better shape than it was before, the code formatting, getting rid of the pic and adding a relevant tag are substantial improvements, each on its own reason enough to approve an edit.

So this edit should have been approved, but I can see why some reviewers might reject it because of the removed comments and indention.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to that noted by Erik, you also failed to deal with the [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) tag which should have been removed. There was some capitalisation that could have been added to the title.

The edit could have been rejected by some reviewers as incomplete, as you are supposed to fix all the faults when making an edit. (Just suggesting further possible reasons)

Comment: While fixing all the problems is ideal, and editors should make an effort to look for additional problems before submitting, falling short of perfection isn't grounds for rejecting an edit.

Comment: Where is the too minor reason when you need it...

Comment: @Luuklag is called "Improve".

Answer (score -4):

I didn't review this, but FWIW if I had - as an Office VBA professional I would probably have rejected it as not an improvement because

- The question is definitely too broad and little to no chance of salvaging it.
- The incorrect `macros` tag was not removed.

Probably, I'd have gone to the question and voted to close. Then I'd have clicked "Reject and Edit" to remove the `macros` tag to get it out of that list. Those are the most important things to have done. Depending on how I was feeling, I might have formatted the macro code, but not necessarily.

Comment: Unfortunately, when doing edit reviews, we are not to judge if the question should have been closed in the first place. I have actually done so myself several times, but I believe the community consensus nowadays is that the edits should be reviewed on their own merit, regardless of the state of the post as whole.

Comment: Possibly, @Lundin although I recall seeing other opinions in discussions, here. Particularly as to whether a review should have been done at all.

Comment: Personally I think editing posts that need to be closed is a huge waste of everyone's time. But apparently the community likes to keep a consistent suggested edits policy or some such.

Comment: Good points. To be honest maybe something should be done about the `macros` tag, considering how many questions have both excel/vba tags and the `macros` tag (1000+), but I'll leave that to people more experienced than I am.

Comment: @M.Douda I regularly monitor that from the vba and ms-word lists, and I know I'm not the only one. Same as I monitor the word tag for things that should be ms-word. I would imagine the  majority of the 1000+ are relatively old...

Comment: Why not just accept and go fix the tag yourself? I think people spend more time thinking than it would take to just deal with it.  Sure if the edit is terrible reject but anyone who writes will tell you that you never get all the errors or needed edits on the first pass.  Don't let the perfect be the enemy of the good. Trite but useful advice.

Comment: Remember that suggested editors can't really vote to close or delete. Plus the question is still open (even with the meta effect in full force) so it might be debatable whether the question should be open or not. Personally I'm not sure about "definitely too broad", it seems very specific to me, and has an accepted answer with *one line of code*.

Comment: Also, FWIW, I've found the "turd polishing" rule hard to understand. I've come across many posts that were in bad shape that I'd kind of like to fix, I take a guess as to whether it's "too bad" to salvage and just downvote and leave a comment if the coin comes up heads. Also that "turd polishing" rule gets awkward when the "turd" is an answer with many upvotes (votes != answer quality, but I've heard that upvoted answers are very hard to delete). Ideally SE should offer more guidance to editors in this case than the (sometimes completely incorrect) "no improvement whatsoever" reason.

Comment: @jrh I think you misunderstand the meaning of "don't polish a turd". It's not a question that is bad that *could* be fixed, ever. It is a question that is bad and cannot be fixed, ever. Hence the phrase "don't polish a turd". E.g. Polish it with all your heart and soul, to within an inch of it's metaphorical life, and it'll still be a turd.