# Ignore tags in relationship with other -> I don't want to see Unity with JavaScript, since I program in C#

Tags: support

Is there a possibility to ignore tags which are together?

For example, I'm currently watching the tags for C# and Unity, and I program with the developing environment of Unity. Unity can be programmed in C# and JavaScript. I don't want to see questions where someone programs in JavaScript.

How can I do it?

Or other: I'm programming C# in Unity and not outside of Unity. How do I ignore questions which have C#, but no Unity?

Comment: I think there should be a new tag `c#-unity`

Comment: Would simply [searching for C# and Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d+c%23) or [Unity and not JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d+-javascript) solve your problem?

Comment: @AmitChigadani No, certainly not, then we would create [the whole excel-vba problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370095/7296893) all over again and apparently fixing that is taking the DAG team two months.

Comment: @ Dukeling I can actually search with tagging: [see in advanced search tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=) , but its just convinience i guess

Comment: You can always create a bookmark to the search, or maybe check out this [question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/custom-question-lists-is-available-for-testing) thing, or just ignore all of [tag:javascript] (or do you want to see non-Unity JavaScript questions?).

Comment: For your first use case, can't you just ignore [javascript]?

Comment: Isn't this something that is going to be in tag-watching, in 6-8 weeks? As team DAG is taking two months to fix this for `[Excel-VBA]` as @ErikvonAsmuth noted.