# Can't fix spelling problems in a question because of VBA tag?

Tags: bug, tags

I tried to fix some typos in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968610) and was blocked by this monstrosity:

> [image]

1. It already has `excel` and `libreoffice` tags, so I have no idea what I'm expected to do here.
2. My edit shouldn't be rejected because of tag issues if my edit has nothing to do with the tags.

So I guess I'll leave it unfixed.

Comment: Question currently has 6 tags, the error message says "enter no more than 5 tags" - I'm guessing this is the problem here. But also, this question hasn't been manually edited in about 4 years, does editing it really add any value?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton 1. I didn't change the tags 2. Of course correcting errors adds value.

Comment: No, you didn't change the tags, but it currently has 6 tags due to what seems like automated tagging, which may bypass the 5 cap. With that said, you probably can't save it now because it has too many tags. As for correcting errors, idk. The question seems pretty clear already, what spelling errors are you trying to change? Any that would be worth boosting this post? Because I don't see any

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton All spelling errors are worth correcting.

Comment: I guess I would agree unless you are bumping a 4-year-old post to change a single word that is already easily understood

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I'm not bumping anything.  I'm fixing errors.  If fixing errors incidentally changes the prominence of posts in an unwanted way, then that's a side effect that should be addressed elsewhere.

Comment: What are those checkboxes under the edit summary, if you don't mind me asking something off-topic? I don't remember seeing those before.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Ah, those are from https://stackapps.com/q/6091/10753

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a rare edge case from when [Shog programmatically added](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace) the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag to all questions with [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)... the rare part here is that this question already had five tags. So now it has six.

Since you said you didn't change the tag, this is the system telling you "Oops, I see six tags. You have to remove one". The long warning message about the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) tag is not a blocking error, but rather a warning. It really should be a yellow caution indicator, certainly once you've met the requirements... but that's a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for another day.

It's akin to when you try to edit a question from the past that has a now-blocked title or an old question with a link to JSFiddle and no code; you have to edit the title/add code before you can submit edits to those questions.

Remember, edits should strive to fix *all* problems with a post.

Comment: Edits that fix a problem should be accepted even if they don't fix *all* problems.

Comment: @endolith:  *Most* purists would disagree there...

Comment: @endolith Yes, any improvement to a post is good; notice I said "should" and not "must". In reality, however, there are costs to consider. Sometimes edits are not worth it (e.g. a <2k user changing the spelling on 1 or 2 words), or there are system-wide requirements for posts that might require you do more to meet the new minimum requirements. Also, the [guidance for the edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) says: "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, *correcting all problems that you observe.*" (emphasis mine)

Comment: @TylerH Yes, but [those are implementation problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92989/130885).  I agree with "*should*, but not *must*".    Anyway, are [these edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20968610/revisions) really "trivial"?

Comment: @endolith The point of the quote was to share the part that I emphasized (that's usually why people point out emphasis they add to quotes they share). I do not imply that any edits you've made here are trivial; I don't even know what edits you attempted to make. The point I am making here is that there is lots of guidance that says you need to pay attention to all the problems with a post when editing, ideally, so it's not really a fault of the system for not letting you proceed past a blocking error that you should have noticed/fixed.

Answer (score 9):

That's my fault; I added an extra tag to a few questions [a while back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace).

I've corrected this now.