# The Problem with Questions about Microsoft Access [access-vba]

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

There is a trend I am noticing with [access-vba] tagged questions:

1. OP posts a fairly good question on a moderately complex Access topic
2. The question fails to encapsulate all that is needed for a good answer
3. Answerers give reasonable advice based on what was presented
4. OP says 'it didn't work'
5. Further attempts to engage OP are ignored, or the problem is abandoned

The problem is it can be really hard to get all of the relevant context together to pose an even moderately involved Access question. Access is not just code, but Queries, Forms, Reports and Macros, and these all might need to be taken into consideration when trying to answer a question.

The best most Access users can do is post a question with only partial information. This can make it difficult to craft an answer that works. The OP often has no idea what parts of the program apply, so they don't know what else to provide in response to comments.

I have been programming Access for nearly 20 years, and I am starting to think that any Access questions beyond the trivial aren't worth the effort to answer on Stack Overflow.

A much quicker and surer approach would be to initiate a Teamviewer session so someone experienced can help the OP through their issues.

Some examples of failed Access questions (I could come up with more):

- [Access VBA: combine GetRows with bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52301616/access-vba-combine-getrows-with-bookmark/52302655#52302655)
- [Appending data to an indexed table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51192806/appending-data-to-an-indexed-table/51254394#51254394)
- [Unrecognised database format(opendatabase error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229654/unrecognised-database-formatopendatabase-error/51252469#51252469)
- [Search Multiple fields on an MS Access form using a textbox linked to a subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527093/search-multiple-fields-on-an-ms-access-form-using-a-textbox-linked-to-a-subform/48648489#48648489)

Comment: There's a reason that there are close reasons for questions not containing enough information to answer, and that site policy is to close such questions instead of answering them.  This right here is why.

Comment: This problem is not restricted to the access-vba section but to all sections as abandoned and "drive-by" questions are quite common. It pays to take care about which questions you choose to answer.

Comment: But this question highlights **your** unrequited answers, not the questions themselves. I'm not sure if this is what meta is for.  You'll also want to beware of the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a stackoverflow question or answer brings additional attention to the Q/A, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention.

Comment: Yes, the examples are mine, but I feel the question is valid beyond my own experience with answers. Any type of feedback is fine, I simply wanted some other eyes on the issue.

Comment: You identified the problem well enough, these a simple problems that users can easily solve by themselves by Googling or getting a basic hint in a comment.  SO no longer has a barrier of entry like it used to, there is no down-side to asking stuff like this.  You have to filter by yourself, a basic one is to not answer old simple questions since nobody gets stuck for that long.  The first one was a help-vampire, "I hadn't yet created a subform" was the cue to get out fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... I am starting to think that any Access questions beyond the trivial aren't worth the effort to answer on StackOverflow.

You're probably right about this, if nothing else but for the fact that you venture into *very* dangerous territory with...

> A much quicker and surer approach would be to initiate a Teamviewer session so someone experienced can help the OP through their issues.

The **network** isn't set up to support a work flow like that.

The real issue then becomes one of scope and one of supported size.  Access questions are too multifaceted for the site and can result in a lot more nuance which regular or fly-by users won't have the patience for.

Maybe it's time for Access to have its own separate network site, with a cabal of experts who could really do it justice?

Comment: I strongly disagree. Lots of subjects are nuanced, this doesn't mean we need a separate site for them, this means we need to step up with providing guidance on how to write good questions for the subject, not a separate site. The issue with the OP wanting to establish Teamviewer sessions and not getting feedback is because the OP answers highly localized questions, and Stack Overflow isn't really suited for that. He instead should focus on more general questions, that are of benefit to more visitors.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth:  My counterargument to this is, if all we can answer are simple questions, then we're not really accomplishing much.  The community for Access database surprisingly *exists* but it already has a stigma about it.  Most database professionals can bluff their way through the ANSI stuff related to Access, but slightly harder (yet still on-topic) problems could easily be out of their reach.  I see no harm in a site spinning off of here with a more narrow focus on this technology so people who actually *have* to use this software can get adequate help.

Comment: I am a user that has to use this software. There's a difference between a _simple_ and a _localized_ question. There are many pretty complex questions, where the answers are still broadly applicable. Generally, most complex issues can be narrowed down to a reproducible problem, even in Access, and even if it concerns forms, tables, SQL and VBA in a single question. I do see harm in creating an access-specific site. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] Most of the problems outlined in the question are because the asker doesn't invest enough effort in the question. If we compromise our quality standards to allow for more localized guidance, help vamirism will likely only increase, and there already is a lot of that on the ms-access tag. Having contributors TeamViewing into computers is a recipe for disaster (it's how most IT scams start), having people download Access databases is disaster too (still the least protected file format that contains VBA, can start hidden unmanaged code on startup).

Comment: My point is that a beginning Access user can easily get in over their head. They can't really be expected to form a complete question. Asking them to invest more effort when they are lost seems kind of pointless. Yes, Teamviewer has its drawbacks, and may not be practicable, but putting that aside, I still feel it would be a better tool for getting people unstuck in situations like this. Please don't read the previous sentence as a suggestion for StackOverflow to offer such a service, or as an indication that I am planning to do so on the side.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow is not really well-suited to answer incomplete questions. But Access-VBA questions can certainly be complete, and get responses.

I personally have answered 341 questions currently that are tagged [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba). 225 got accepted, and 60 have no votes and are not accepted. Of those 60, only [20](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/944360/my-answers-on-questions-that-have-0-score-and-no-comment-by-the-op?UserId=7296893) have no comment and no other accepted answer. So while there certainly are examples of non-engagement, I'd say generally it's pretty low.

You need to account for the fact that Stack Overflow is very much fast-paced. If you answer a couple of days late, the OP has had a couple of days to work on the problem, and pretty likely has already solved it. If no-one engaged on the subject, the OP is likely to not give us feedback on how he solved it.

Also, keep in mind Stack Overflow's main goal is to build a database of knowledge. Providing solutions for specific users is a positive side-effect. If the OP struggles with a highly localized problem that involves multiple database objects (forms/queries/etc.) that indeed is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. But many, many access-vba problems are not like that. The ones you've shared kind-of are.

If you want to help the authors with debugging, I recommend you at least try to respond to more recent questions, but Stack Overflow likely isn't the place for you. Generally, we expect access-vba questions to have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), just like any question on SO. You might say that's harder because there are forms, tables and code involved, but that's true too for most database-oriented applications, like .Net WinForms applications.

---

If you want more fulfillment answering access-vba questions, I recommend the following:

1. Focus on recent questions. The older, the more likely you get no response.
2. Focus on questions where you're nearly 100% sure about the answer. If you can't be, you can ask for additional information if you want to help
3. Make sure the answer has all relevant tags to get feedback from other community members than the OP. For [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba), that's at least [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access), [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba). We have some great experts following [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) but not [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba). Review [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370095/7296893) for current tagging guidance on these questions, in the future, likely we will only have [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) and [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba).

---

Now, let's also go through your examples with a fine tooth comb:

Your first example:

The question was incomplete, since OP didn't report an error or their form structure. You assumed a lot, answered a day late, and got a response. You responded to that response 5 days later. I assume the OP didn't sit on the issue for 5 days, and fixed it in the mean time, nothing really unusual there. Probably shouldn't have answered that one.

Your second example:

OP doesn't want to use an autonumber, and wants to specify incrementally increasing IDs in an append query. Your answer is: use an autonumber. Generally not very helpful, I assume the OP has reasons not to do that in the first place. No need to use complex SQL converting a number to an autonumber, Access can do that through the GUI. Also, 4 days late. No wonder you don't get any response.

Your third example:

The comment by Storax likely properly identifies the issue, the issue is that the OP has set a reference to an old DAO version in an Excel file. Any DAO version before DAO 3.6 will throw an *Unrecognized database format* error when trying to open an accdb database since it can only open MDB databases.

These old DAO versions are often still present, since the newer ones don't support ODBCDirect. A DAO reference certainly is not generic, that's nonsense, there are multiple versions, with a large difference between ACEDAO (DAO >3.6) and the older JET ones. If you use Access as the host application, you always have the correct one referenced for your version of Access, but OP is running the code from Excel.

If you assumed corruption, you could start by asking if OP could actually open the database, they nearly always can because that's the first thing you try when you get that error, but since we already have an upvoted comment identifying the issue, the only reasonable thing to do is ask the author of that comment to post it as an answer.

Your fourth example:

Not much to say here, this is a bad question and any answer will be a guess.