# Can we get an update on the status of the excel-vba tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This tag's description ([excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba)) says it is pending removal, but the meta post made about removing it was created almost 6 months ago ([Merging the [excel-vba] into [vba] - speak now, or forever hold your peace](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370095/merging-the-excel-vba-into-vba-speak-now-or-forever-hold-your-peace/370101#370101)) - have there been any updates on what's going to happen to this tag?

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. Isn't this where we ask questions like the above? +

Comment: @QHarr Right? No idea

Comment: It's already been over a year...